# null coalescing operator assignment to self

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, null, null-coalescing-operator

I currently have two scripts set up in Unity to handle some UI Audio. One is a manager and the other is there to play a sound for a specific UI element. A simplified version of what I have is this:

```
public class AudioUIManager : MonoBehaviour //Only one of these in the scene
{
    public AudioClip genericUISound; //This is set in the inspector.
}
```

---

```
public class AudioUITextAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip specifiedUISound; //This is not set in the inspector
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioUIManager audioUIManager; // I get a reference to this elsewhere

    void Start()
    {
        //Use generic sounds from audio manager if nothing is specified.
        specifiedUISound = specifiedUISound ?? audioUIManager.genericUISound;
        print(specifiedUISound);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have the `specifiedUISound` field use the sound that it is assigned to it in the inspector. If no sound is assigned then use the generic sound from the UI manager. This saves me assigning the same sound to millions of buttons that require the same sound but gives me the option of having a specific sound for one button if I want to.

**However**, the null-coalessing operator is asigning `null` to `specifiedUISound` even though **it is null and the `audioUIManager`'s sound is not**. Also, I can get this to work if I use the ternary operator to check for null like so:

```
specifiedUISound = specifiedUIsound == null ? audioUIManager.genericUISound : specifiedUISound;
```

Am I misunderstanding the null coalescing operator? Why does this happen?

**Edit:** Jerry Switalski has pointed out that this only happens when the `specifiedUISound` is serialized. (if it is `public` or if it has the `[SerializeField]` attribute). Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: s = s ?? "test"; works fine here

Comment: So you're saying that `foo = foo ?? bar` doesn't work, but that `foo = foo == null ? bar : foo` does? Unity didn't change C# rules, so it must be your code. Did you perhaps go too far in creating a [mcve] so that you removed too much relevant code? What type is `AudioClip`, is it a struct or a class?

Comment: Yeah, I tested this example and it recreates the problem. If you make these two classes and add them to two different game objects in unity then it re-creates it! It works normally if I don't use it in this way though obviously.

Comment: I believe that `audioUIManager.genericUISound` is `null` while the code is being executed and only becomes non-null later on. Have you debugged this scenario and actually seen the behaviour live? Please output the value of `audioUIManager.genericUISound` before the code is executed.

Comment: @NineBerry Just checked and `audioUIManager.genericUISound` isn't null before hand. Also, the method with the ternary operator wouldn't work either if it was null.

Comment: @NineBerry To add to that, the `specifiedUISound` prints `null` beforehand as well. This is very strange...

Comment: @CodeCaster just realised you asked about `AudioClip`. It's part of the Unity API. [It's a class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html)

Comment: Why not just use the if statement and save your precious time?
      `if (specifiedUISound==null)
        {
            specifiedUISound = audioUIManager.genericUISound;
        }`

Comment: @Programmer Yeah, I think I can get it to work a bunch of ways. I'm just curious as to why the null coalescing operator isn't doing it's job in this case! I don't like leaving gaps in my knowledge like this haha.

Comment: why in the name of goodness would you be using "[SerializeField]" ?  something's drastically wrong if you are using that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're running into Unity's [custom equality operator](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/):

> When a MonoBehaviour has fields, in the editor only, we do not set those fields to “real null”, but to a “fake null” object. Our custom == operator is able to check if something is one of these fake null objects, and behaves accordingly. While this is an exotic setup, it allows us to store information in the fake null object that gives you more contextual information when you invoke a method on it, or when you ask the object for a property. Without this trick, you would only get a NullReferenceException, a stack trace, but you would have no idea which GameObject had the MonoBehaviour that had the field that was null.

While running in the editor, Unity replaces your serialized `null` with a sentinel value that isn't actually `null`. This allows them to provide more informative error messages in some circumstances.

Is `specifiedUISound` equal to `null`? That depends on how you ask. C# has multiple notions of "equality", including [data equality and reference equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869601/c-sharp-equals-referenceequals-and-operator).

Some checks will say the values are equal: `==` and `Object.Equals`

Others will say they are not equal: `??` and `Object.ReferenceEquals`

This behavior will only occur in the editor. When running in a standalone build, any `null` values will just be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not really complete answer to your question and very intresting example, but I ran few tests, and it looks like the problem is in `SerializeField` attribute.

When I run this (`someObj` is assigned from inspector `nullObj` is left empty):

```
    public AudioClip someObj;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip nullObj;

    void Start () 
    {
        Debug.Log("nullObj == null : " + (nullObj == null));
        Debug.Log("someObj == null : " + (someObj == null));

        nullObj = nullObj ?? someObj;

        Debug.Log ("nullObj == null : " + (nullObj == null));
    }
```

I have this prints:

[image]

However getting rid of `SerializeField` attribute, makes things work as intended:

```
    public AudioClip someObj;

    private AudioClip nullObj;

    void Start () 
    {
        Debug.Log("nullObj == null : " + (nullObj == null));
        Debug.Log("someObj == null : " + (someObj == null));

        nullObj = nullObj ?? someObj;

        Debug.Log ("nullObj == null : " + (nullObj == null));
    }
```

gives:

[image]

So reasuming:

I don't really know the root of the problem, but what is fact is that Unity3D serializing fields breaks null coalescing operator in Mono engine. I still don't know how, but maybe just due to changing `==` operator of seriazlized type??

Anyway I hope it helps at least a little bit.

Comment: Very interesting, nice find!

Comment: I hope it helps, actually you can also reproduce it just by leaving the nullObj as public (Unity will serilize this filed automaticly) - then even if is null, given operator will not work correctly.

Comment: Awesome, super helpful. I'll wait and see if anyone knows why this happens and accept this if not!

Comment: @gjttt1 This answer is not true. I am still envestigating and will let you know

Comment: He's right about public and serialized stuff but it does happen only in the editor. It should work fine when you build it.