# Equals on boxed string

Tags: c#, string, object, boxing

Would someone please explain to me why boxing strings results in `false` return values? I don't understand ...

```
string a = string.Format("{0}{1}", "abc", "123");
string b = "abc123";
string c = "abc123";
Console.WriteLine(a == b);
Console.WriteLine((object)a == (object)b);
Console.WriteLine(c == b);
Console.WriteLine((object)c == (object)b);
```

Comment: Strings are reference types, and cannot be boxed.  Your problem is that `==` binds to _compile-time_ types.

Comment: Also, the strings referenced by `b` and `c` are interned, so they will _probably_ be the same reference, which will be different from `a`.  Bottom line, use `Equals` for value equality instead of `==`

Comment: @DStanley: No; bottom line, don't cast to `object`.

Comment: @SLaks but `Equals` will use value semantics even if you _do_ cast to `object`.

Comment: I think, you should look at [another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3869613/364429). It must be very helpful for you I guess.