# C#: how to get first char of a string?

Tags: c#, string

Can the first `char` of a string be retrieved by doing the following?

```
MyString.ToCharArray[0]
```

Comment: What did you learn when you tried it?

Comment: @Michael: There was a compiler error. How are you meant to use ToCharArray if not this way?

Comment: For the record, `ToCharArray` is a *method*, you should run it first, eg `char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();`, and then use `char first = chars[0];`. You can also butcher it into `str.ToCharArray()[0];`. Either way, make sure you check the string isn't null and has at least one character - you can do it using `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))`.

Comment: Craig.. the usage of ToCharArray is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: Do you want the first **`char`** or the first **character**? If you try this and it seems to work, try again with `` or ``, which both failed in a program I was using that was written in C# with this exact bug.

Comment: @hippietrail - thx, that got me reading to see if C# had any special built-in functions to deal with Unicode complexities. As best I could see, one would first call `String.Normalize` with a specified Normalization Form, to make the string easier to analyze, then write custom code to extract each `Unicode codepoint`, and determine which codepoints start a character, vs those that add diacritic marks or other control purposes. Also found http://stackoverflow.com/a/26977869/199364 which mentions some subtleties of the concept **character**.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Just `MyString[0]`.  This uses the [String.Chars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) indexer.

Answer (score 68):

`Mystring[0]` should be enough

Comment: Shouldn't 'a spent those extra five seconds typing the words, "should be enough".

Comment: Who answered this question first?

Comment: Select the oldest tab to see that it as Matthew

Comment: @johnc: Or better, hover over the timestamp.

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
string s1="good"; 
string s=s1.Substring(0,1);
```

Comment: The difference between this answer and the chosen one is that this solution returns a string, and the other returns a char.

Comment: char get only one character but my solution can be result more than one if you want.

Comment: It was just a precision as the type can be of importance according to what you want to do with it.

Comment: You probably want to check that the string length is not 0.

Answer (score 27):

You can use LINQ

```
char c = mystring.FirstOrDefault()
```

It will be equal to `'\0'` if the string is empty.

Answer (score 22):

The difference between `MyString[0]` and `MyString.ToCharArray()[0]` is that the former treats the string as a read-only array, while `ToCharArray()` creates a new array. The former will be quicker (along with easier) for almost anything where it will work, but `ToCharArray` can be necessary if you have a method that needs to accept an array, or if you want to change the array.

If the string isn't known to be non-null and non-empty you could do:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString) ? (char?)null : MyString[0]
```

which returns a `char?` of either null or the first character in the string, as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `char?` as a way to include the possibility "there is no first character".

Answer (score 12):

Just another approach:

```
string mystr = "hello";
MessageBox.show(mystr.Substring(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 11):

Or you can do this:

```
MyString[0];
```

Comment: @Robert, naw, I wanna see it one more time, just to be sure!

Comment: I just didn't see the ones before mine :)

Comment: no worries.  I do it all the time too.  I'm a really slow typer.

Answer (score 10):

Starting with C# 8.0+ we can use the range indexer syntax.

The following code:

```cs
var name = "Dotnet".Substring(0, 1)
```

can be written using range syntax:

```
var name = "Dotnet"[..1]
```

[Try it out in Dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K2FyV1)

[See official docs for more examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-)

The above code will throw if the input string is less than range index. This LINQ will prevent that problem:

```
var name = "Dotnet".Take(1).ToArray()
```

[Try it out in Dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nuOsu4)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this `MyString.ToCharArray()[0]`

:)

But you can use `MyString[0]` too.

Answer (score 3):

**Following example for getting first character from a string might help someone**

```
string anyNameForString = "" + stringVariableName[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 8 you can use ranges.

```
myString[0..Math.Min(myString.Length, 1)]
```

Add a `?` after `myString` to handle `null` strings.

Comment: I believe that this returns `string` and not `char` which in my case is what I wanted, so thanks, but may not be technically what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

MyString.Remove(1, 2); also works

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is NO.

Correct is MyString[position of character]. For your case MyString[0], 0 is the FIRST character of any string.

A character value is designated with ' (single quote), like this x character value is written as 'x'.

A string value is designated with " ( double quote), like this x string value is written as "x".

So Substring() method is also does not return a character, Substring() method returns a string!!!

A string is an array of characters, and last character must be '\0' (null) character. Thats the difference between character array and string ( which is an array of characters with last character as "end of string marker" '\0' null.

And also notice that 'x' IS NOT EQUAL to "x".
Because "x" is actually 'x'+'\0'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. I'm using `txtModel_Leave` event then create method to detect the first char in main textbox.

```
private void txtMain_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    detectFirstChar();
}

private void detectFirstChar() 
{
    string mystr = txtModel.Text;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtModel.Text))
    {
        txtAwalan.Text = "";
    }
    else if (mystr.Substring(0, 1) == "F")
    {
        txtKategori.Text = "Finishing";               
    }
    else if((mystr.Substring(0, 1) == "H"))
    {
        txtKategori.Text = "Half";
    }
    else
    {
        txtKategori.Text = "NONE";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Answer (score -1):

getting a char from a string may depend on the enconding (string default is UTF-16)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32141891

```
string str = new String(new char[] { '\uD800', '\uDC00', 'z' });
string first = str.Substring(0, char.IsHighSurrogate(str[0]) ? 2 : 1);
```

Comment: How is this an answer?