# How to get the first five character of a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, char

I have read this [question to get first char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3878820/1716774)  of the string. Is there a way to get the first n number of characters from a string in C#?

Comment: The previous question is asking about **`char`**s and you are asking about **character**s. They are not the same thing. `` and `` are two characters I needed to use just yesterday which failed in the software written in C# I was using because the programmer didn't know the difference between a `char` and a character. Don't fall into this trap!

Answer (score 303):

You can use [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) like:

```
char[] array = yourStringVariable.Take(5).ToArray();
```

Or you can use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string str = yourStringVariable.Substring(0,5);
```

Remember that `String.Substring` could throw an exception in case of string's length  less than the characters required.

If you want to get the result back in string then you can use:

- Using String Constructor and LINQ's `Take`

  ```
  string firstFivChar = new string(yourStringVariable.Take(5).ToArray());
  ```

The plus with the approach is not checking for length before hand.

- The other way is to use `String.Substring` with error checking

like:

```
string firstFivCharWithSubString = 
    !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourStringVariable) && yourStringVariable.Length >= 5
    ? yourStringVariable.Substring(0, 5)
    : yourStringVariable;
```

Comment: string val = new string(yourStringVariable.Take(6).ToArray());
 
but Substring will error if length of yourStringVariable is less than 5

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is wrong here.  Consider a string with 10 blanks - your code will return all 10.  Use `IsNullOrEmpty` instead. (It isn't good to combine `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` with any other test; Instead test for null+empty, then `Trim` if that is specified behavior, then do whatever tests/operations are needed.)

Comment: You can save a call to ToArray() by using String.Concat() like so: string firstFivChar = String.Concat(yourStringVariable.Take(5));

Comment: you can check StringVariable.length>5  in if condition and use substring(0,5)

Answer (score 61):

Please try:

```
yourString.Substring(0, 5);
```

Check [C# Substring](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring&q=substring%20in%20c#&ei=-1ZmUYySBMPprQfJ24CoBQ&usg=AFQjCNEJzDmg40WvOmut6Ei3Zn6eFBT3YQ), [String.Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This will through an exception if length of `yourString` is less than 5. To avoid exception, we can substring based on the condition, such as, `yourString.Length <= 5 ? yourString : yourString.Substring(0, 5)`

Answer (score 45):

You can use [Substring(int startIndex, int length)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

```
string result = str.Substring(0,5);
```

> The substring starts at a specified character position and has a
>   specified length. This method does not modify the value of the current
>   instance. Instead, it returns a new string with length characters
>   starting from the startIndex position in the current string,
>   [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

What if the source string is less then five characters? You will get exception by using above method. We can put condition to check if the number of characters in string are more then 5 then get first five through Substring. Note I have assigned source string to firstFiveChar variable. The firstFiveChar not change if characters are less then 5, so else part is not required.

```
string firstFiveChar = str;
If(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourStringVariable) && yourStringVariable.Length >= 5)
      firstFiveChar = yourStringVariable.Substring(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 43):

No one mentioned how to make proper checks when using `Substring()`, so I wanted to contribute about that.

If you don't want to use `Linq` and go with `Substring()`, you have to make sure that your string is bigger than the second parameter (length) of `Substring()` function.

Let's say you need the first 5 characters. You should get them with proper check, like this:

```
string title = "love"; // 15 characters
var firstFiveChars = title.Length <= 5 ? title : title.Substring(0, 5);

// firstFiveChars: "love" (4 characters)
```

Without this check, `Substring()` function would throw an exception because it'd iterate through letters that aren't there.

I think you get the idea...

Comment: lovely extra bit of info

Comment: I am glad you liked it.

Comment: This helped me a lot, but could you explain what exactly it's doing in that line?

Comment: I would check some examples about substring. It takes parameters for indexes. The starting index is 0. If you write anything bigger (or smaller, for that matter) than the last index of any array, you get an out of index exception. That check, in the example is for avoiding that exception.

Answer (score 26):

Just a heads up there is a new way to do this in C# 8.0: **Range operators**

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

Or as I like to call em, Pandas slices.

Old way:

```
string newString = oldstring.Substring(0, 5);
```

New way:

```
string newString = oldstring[..5];
```

Which at first glance appears like a pretty bad tradeoff of some readability for shorter code but the new feature gives you

1. a standard syntax for slicing arrays (and therefore strings)
2. cool stuff like this:

   var slice1 = list[2..^3];               // list[Range.Create(2, Index.CreateFromEnd(3))]

   var slice2 = list[..^3];                // list[Range.ToEnd(Index.CreateFromEnd(3))]

   var slice3 = list[2..];                 // list[Range.FromStart(2)]

   var slice4 = list[..];                  // list[Range.All]

Comment: This suffers from the same string length problem: you have to check it first or it can throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel so check first? The answer solves the problem, we shouldn't be coding afraid of exceptions.

Answer (score 25):

The problem with `.Substring(,)` is, that you need to be sure that the given string has at least the length of the asked number of characters, otherwise an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` will be thrown.

**Solution 1 (using 'Substring'):**

```
var firstFive = stringValue != null && stringValue.Length > 5 ? 
                   stringValue.Substring(0, 5) :
                   stringValue;
```

The drawback of using `.Substring(` is that you'll need to check the length of the given string.

**Solution 2 (using 'Take'):**

```
var firstFive = stringValue != null ? 
                    string.Join("", stringValue.Take(5)) : 
                    null;
```

Using **'Take'** will prevent that you need to check the length of the given string.

Answer (score 16):

Use the PadRight function to prevent the string from being too short, grab what you need then trim the spaces from the end all in one statement.

```
strSomeString = strSomeString.PadRight(50).Substring(0,50).TrimEnd();
```

Comment: This is the better solution so far. Using only Substring can cause error when the length of string is lower than the substring length.

Comment: best alternative for LEFT function that we use in SQL Server

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why anybody mentioned this.
But it's the shortest and simplest way to achieve this.

```
string str = yourString.Remove(n);
```

`n` - number of characters that you need

Example

```
var zz = "7814148471";
Console.WriteLine(zz.Remove(5));
//result - 78141
```

Comment: This is internally the same as "this.Substring(0, 5)", so you need to make sure the string has the proper length.

Comment: In a case where you want the first n characters, this only works if you know the length of the string. If the length can change, this will not always work. I know that is probably obvious to most, but just mentioning it for any one who passes by...

Comment: Also, if n is equal to the length of the string, it throws an error, unlike substring

Answer (score 10):

Append five whitespace characters then cut off the first five and trim the result.  The number of spaces you append should match the number you are cutting. Be sure to include the parenthesis before `.Substring(0,X)` or you'll append nothing.

```
string str = (yourStringVariable + "    ").Substring(0,5).Trim();
```

With this technique you won't have to worry about the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` mentioned in other answers.

Comment: darn I was going to post that!! upvoted. (it's 2019, why can't there be a method on string that does what Mid$ did in 1985? For those who say 'you shouldn't do that' OK you come write my code for me...you will have to do it...)

Answer (score 7):

```
string str = "GoodMorning"

string strModified = str.Substring(0,5);
```

Comment: will error if length of variable "str" is less than 5

Answer (score 6):

This is how you do it in 2020:

```cs
var s = "ABCDEFGH";
var first5 = s.AsSpan(0, 5);
```

A [Span<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1) points directly to the memory of the string, avoiding allocating a temporary string. Of course, any subsequent method asking for a `string` requires a conversion:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(first5.ToString());
```

Though, these days many `.NET` APIs allow for spans. Stick to them if possible!

**Note:** If targeting `.NET Framework` add a reference to the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) package, but don't expect the same superb performance.

Comment: We really need to see the .net version before using `AsSpan`

Comment: "In 2020" pretty much implies that you're targeting `.NET 5` or at least `.NET Core`. Anyway, it works in `.NET Framework 4.5+` if you add some dependencies.

Comment: If you have to call .ToString() to get the substring, doesn't this allocate a new string ? Then the initial reason of "avoiding allocating a temporary string" is not a reason anymore to use this way.

Comment: @AlexandruDicu I think the answer is very clear on this point. It depends on what you intend to do with the result. `Console.WriteLine` did not support `Span<T>` at the time of writing, but many other `.NET` APIs do.

Comment: Is it just me or `AsSpan()` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if string `s` is shorter than 5 character (in the above example). It may be worth checking for length is my point.

Comment: Sure it will throw. If you don't want the exception you should of course check the length first.

Answer (score 4):

In [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) you can get the first five characters of a string like so

```
string str = data[0..5];
```

Here is some more information about [Indices And Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Comment: Sadly this still throws an exception if the string is shorter that the requested length

Answer (score 3):

To get the first n number of characters from a string in C#

```
String yourstring="Some Text";  
String first_n_Number_of_Characters=yourstring.Substring(0,n);
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# 8 you can use [Range Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes). In order to avoid the exception if your original string is shorter than the desired length, you can use `Math.Min`:

```cs
string newString = oldstring[..Math.Min(oldstring.Length, 5)];
```

Of course, if you know that the original string is longer, you can optimize:

```cs
string newString = oldstring[..5];
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an extension method that checks if a string is bigger than what was needed and shortens the string to the defined max amount of chars and appends '...'.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Ellipsis(this string s, int charsToDisplay)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            return s.Length <= charsToDisplay ? s : new string(s.Take(charsToDisplay).ToArray()) + "...";
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try this code when str is less than 5.

```
string strModified = str.Substring(0,str.Length>5?5:str.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
var firstFive = stringValue?.Substring(0, stringValue.Length >= 5 ? 5 : customAlias.Length);
```

or alternative if you want to check for Whitespace too (instead of only Null):

```
var firstFive = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) && stringValue.Length >= 5 ? stringValue.Substring(0, 5) : stringValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [String.ToCharArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5(v=vs.110).aspx). 
It takes `int startindex` and and `int length` as parameters and returns a `char[]`

```
new string(stringValue.ToCharArray(0,5))
```

You would still need to make sure the string has the proper length, otherwise it will throw a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using, it has no problem with string less than required characters

```
private string TakeFirstCharacters(string input, int characterAmount)
{
    return input?.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, characterAmount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want only first 5 characters from any field, then this can be achieved by Left Attribute

```
Vessel = f.Vessel !=null ? f.Vessel.Left(5) : ""
```

Comment: what library is this in?

Answer (score 0):

string Substring(START, LENGTH) return sub string from START with length of LENGTH.

I've added a SafeSubString method in order to prevent ArgumentAoutOfRangeException, in case LENGTH is bigger than original string size.

use:

```
var s = "aa";
var ss = s.SafeSubString(30);
Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

output: "aa"

extension method

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string SafeSubString(this string str, int maxSize)
    {
        if (maxSize <= 0)
            return string.Empty;
        
        if (str.Length <= maxSize)
            return str;

        return str.Substring(0, maxSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try below code

```
 string Name = "Abhishek";
 string firstfour = Name.Substring(0, 4);
 Response.Write(firstfour);
```

Comment: This is not any different from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15942016/6198927 and this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/15942008/6198927

Answer (score -3):

I have tried the above answers and the best i think is this one

```
@item.First_Name.Substring(0,1)
```

In this i could get the first letter of the string