# string[0] get first character from string

Tags: c#, string, casting

I have a problem which I do not understand. Here is my code:

```
String input = "3 days ago"
String firstCharacter = input[0].ToString(); //Returns 3
int firstCharacter = (int)input[0];  //Returns 51
```

Why does it return 51?

PS: My code comes from this thread: [C#: how to get first char of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878820/c-how-to-get-first-char-of-a-string)

More information:

```
In case that input = "5 days ago", then int firstCharacter is 53.
```

Comment: Because the `3` is a char with `51` code. You cast a char to an int. Check http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is normal behavior in .NET. You can cast a char to int and int to char.

Comment: Maybe `int.TryParse` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting a `char` to `int` in this way will give you its **ASCII** value which for 3 is equal to 51. You can find a full list here:

http://www.ascii-code.com/

You want to do something like this instead:

```
Char.GetNumericValue(input[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **substring** to extract it as a string instead of a char and avoid having to cast it:

```
        string input = "3 days ago";
        string sFirstCharacter = input.Substring(0, 1);   
        int nFirstCharacter = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, 1));
```