# Linq Query keeps throwing "Unable to create a constant value of type System.Object....", Why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, entity-framework

The following is the code sample:

```
private void loadCustomer(int custIdToQuery) 
    {
        var dbContext = new SampleDB();
        try
        {
            var customerContext = from t in dbContext.tblCustomers      // keeps throwing:
                                   where t.CustID.Equals(custIdToQuery) // Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. 
                                   select new                           // Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') 
                                   {                                    // are supported in this context.
                                       branchId = t.CustomerBranchID,   //
                                       branchName = t.BranchName        //
                                   };                                   //

            if (customerContext.ToList().Count() < 1) //Already Tried customerContext.Any()
            {
                lstbCustomers.DataSource = customerContext;
                lstbCustomers.DisplayMember = "branchName";
                lstbCustomers.ValueMember = "branchId";
            }
            else
            {
                lstbCustomers.Items.Add("There are no branches defined for the selected customer.");
                lstbCustomers.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

i am unable to understand what am i doing wrong. I keep getting **"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."**

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Use == instead of Equals:

```
where t.CustID == custIdToQuery
```

If the types are incorrect you may find that this doesn't compile.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between "t.CustID == custIdToQuery" and "t.CustID.Equals(custIdToQuery)". thanks in advance

Comment: @Neel Take a look at this question for explanation on the difference between `==` and `.Equals()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue with a nullable int. Using == instead works nicely, but if you want to use .Equals, you can compare it to the value of the nullable variable, so

```
where t.CustID.Value.Equals(custIdToQuery)
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue when I was trying to do .Equals with a nullable decimal. Using == instead works nicely. I guess this is because it's not trying to match the exact "type" of decimal? to decimal.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is in the context of an `IQueryable`, so it's not compiled into regular C# code.  It becomes an expression that is passed to a query provider.  That query provider can do whatever wants with the query, and it may handle `Equals` and `==` the same or not.

Comment: I used `.Equal()` to compare `Int32?` with `Int32`. Since `Int32?` is supposed to contain `Int32` and `null`, I thought it would work. But it didn't. `==` worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced the same issue and i was comparing Collection Object `"User"` with integer data type `"userid"` (`x.User.Equals(userid)`)

```
from user in myshop.UserPermissions.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.User.Equals(userid))
```

and correct Query is `x.UserId.Equals(userid)`

```
from user in myshop.UserPermissions.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.UserId.Equals(userid))
```

Comment: This is a different problem, you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: how it's different. while i have faced same issue. i just post this answer for reference only for others.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed the direct call of `(sender as Button).Text` to indirect call using a temp var, has worked. 
working code:

```
private void onTopAccBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var name = (sender as Button).Text;
        accountBindingSource.Position =
                    accountBindingSource.IndexOf(_dataService.Db.Accounts.First(ac => ac.AccountName == name));
        accountBindingSource_CurrentChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

buggy code:

```
private void onTopAccBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        accountBindingSource.Position =
                    accountBindingSource.IndexOf(_dataService.Db.Accounts.First(ac => ac.AccountName == (sender as Button).Text));
        accountBindingSource_CurrentChanged(sender, e);
    }
```