# Whats the difference between using String.Equals(str1,str2) and str1 == str2

Tags: c#, string, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# difference between `==` and .Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-difference-between-and-equals)

In my daily code routine I use them a lot, but really don't know how exactly they are different from each other.

```
if(String.Equals(str1, str2))
```

and

```
if(str1 == str2)
```

Comment: Please don't close. This is **not a duplicate** of difference between `==` and `object.Equals` -- although that is a good link. Both `string.Equals(a,b)` and `string.==` are *not* polymorphic, which is the big difference between `==` and `object.Equals`.

Comment: voting to close, these two questions can clearly be merged.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I disagree. This is a *specific* question about two *specific* ways of doing a *string comparison*. The "duplicate question" talks about `==`/`object.Equals` in *general*. Perhaps `string.Equals` could also be mentioned, but this would be lost in a merge.

Comment: @pst that's fine to disagree, but if you read the other question that is proposed by ChrisF you can see that it clearly illustrates the difference.  Therefore merging or deletion of this duplicate would work.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I read the other question, and the responses. None are a satisfactory answer which covers [`static bool string.Equals(string,string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325.aspx) -- this method is not the same as [`string.Equals(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx). Since the other question is *general*, and this is *specific*, a merge/close is inadvisable in my mind.

Comment: If you read the responses `pst` you would see that `BlueMonk` and `Merhdad` both have the pieces to answer the question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Please read my last comment. BlueMonk and Merhdad are talking about the *non-static* [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) method. This question is about the *static* [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325.aspx) method.

Comment: @pst if this is about the static version the OP didn't do a good job explaining it.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Please note the question contains `String.Equals(str1, str2)` (perhaps better as `string.Equals(str1, str2)`) and not `str1.Equals(str2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### (UPDATE)

They are in fact exactly the same.

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return Equals(a, b);
}
```

so `==` calls the `Equals`.

---

```
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
    return ((a == b) || (((a != null) && (b != null)) && EqualsHelper(a, b)));
}
```

`EqualsHelper` is an unsafe method:

**UPDATE**
*What it does, it loops through the characters using integer pointers and compares them as integers (4byte at a time). It does it 10 at a time and then one at a time.*

```
private static unsafe bool EqualsHelper(string strA, string strB)
{
    int length = strA.Length;
    if (length != strB.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    fixed (char* chRef = &strA.m_firstChar)
    {
        fixed (char* chRef2 = &strB.m_firstChar)
        {
            char* chPtr = chRef;
            char* chPtr2 = chRef2;
            while (length >= 10)
            {
                if ((((*(((int*) chPtr)) != *(((int*) chPtr2))) || (*(((int*) (chPtr + 2))) != *(((int*) (chPtr2 + 2))))) || ((*(((int*) (chPtr + 4))) != *(((int*) (chPtr2 + 4)))) || (*(((int*) (chPtr + 6))) != *(((int*) (chPtr2 + 6)))))) || (*(((int*) (chPtr + 8))) != *(((int*) (chPtr2 + 8)))))
                {
                    break;
                }
                chPtr += 10;
                chPtr2 += 10;
                length -= 10;
            }
            while (length > 0)
            {
                if (*(((int*) chPtr)) != *(((int*) chPtr2)))
                {
                    break;
                }
                chPtr += 2;
                chPtr2 += 2;
                length -= 2;
            }
            return (length <= 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly does the bit extra do? At first glance it looks like a bitwise comparison. But wouldn't `==` return true in that case anyways? Is it something locale related?

Comment: so is there any cases where str1 == str2 wont equals String.Equals(str1,srt2)?

Comment: @Remon if you look at the question that this is a `proposed` duplicate of you will find your answer.

Comment: The update doesn't really explain when == and EqualsHelper give different results.

Comment: They are exactly the same. Please see my latest update.

Comment: `==` in the `Equals` in fact is the reference comparison.

Comment: So it's a reflector bug that decodes it as `a==b` instead of `(object)a==(object)b`? In the form reflector decompiles it it looks like infinite recursion to me.

Comment: Sure, it cannot be recursion, it is just as you said `(object)a==(object)b`

Comment: Then can somebody who as an account there post it in the reflector forum and ask why it's decompiled like this/report it as a bug?

Answer (score 2):

They are absolutely the same. Here is what ildasm shows for ==

```
  IL_0002:  call       bool System.String::Equals(string,
                                              string)
```

Also read the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx
It says

> This operator is implemented using the Equals method

Comment: intermediate language disassembler -  a disassembler for .net byte-code

Comment: ildasm is the tool that shows the IL code for a .NET assembly. It is part of the SDK and its location depends on the actual version of the framework. For example C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin