# Difference between == and Equals in C#

Tags: c#, .net, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# difference between `==` and .Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

For comparing two variables we can use == or Equals method. for example,

```
        string a = new string(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'});
        string b = new string(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'});

        Console.WriteLine (a==b);
        Console.WriteLine (a.Equals(b));
```

My question is When should I use == and when should I use Equals? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Next time, search before you ask... there is an exact duplicate of your question already!

Comment: If you are a component maker, you'll encounter the `==` inconsistencies. Better use anyTypeHere.Equals, or object.Equals http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/08/getting-default-of-type-during-runtime.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

== is an operator, which, when not overloaded means "reference equality" for classes (and field-wise equality for structs), but which can be overloaded. A consequence of it being an overload rather than an override is that it is not polymorphic.

Equals is a virtual method; this makes it polymorphic, but means you need to be careful not to call it on null instances.

As a rule of thumb:

- if you know the type of something, and know it has an == overload (most core types such as string, int, float, etc have == meanings), then use ==
- if you don't know the type, Equals(a,b) may be recommended, as this avoids the null issue
- if you really want to check for the same instance (reference equality), consider using ReferenceEquals(a,b), as this will work even if the == is overloaded and Equals overridden
- when using generics, consider `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a,b)` which avoids the null issue, supports Nullable-of-T, and supports IEquatable-of-T

Comment: If == is comparison by reference, then why comparison between two primitive types returns true if the values are equal? Like this:
~~~
a = 3 // has it's own reference
b = 3 // has it's own different reference
a == b // is true
~~~
Why? The references are different so this should  have returned false, right?

Comment: @arm I didn't say "== is comparison by reference" - I said **when not overloaded** it means reference equality for classes, and field-wise equality for structs; "primitives" is a loose term - it looks like you're talking about `System.Int32` (aka `int`); `int` *does* overload `==` (including at the compiler level), and *unless you are boxing*: those **aren't references at all** - they are values, so it is meaningless to ask if the references are equal or different

Answer (score 5):

This post by John Skeet will answer your question:

> So, when should you use which operator? My rule of thumb is that for
>   almost all reference types, use Equals when you want to test equality
>   rather than reference identity. The exception is for strings -
>   comparing strings with == does make things an awful lot simpler and
>   more readable but you need to remember that both sides of the operator
>   must be expressions of type string in order to get the comparison to
>   work properly.
>
> For value types, I'd normally use == for easier-to-read code. Things
>   would get tricky if a value type provided an overload for == which
>   acted differently to Equals, but I'd consider such a type very badly
>   designed to start with.
>
> [Author: Jon Skeet]

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> When == is used on an object type, it'll resolve to
>   System.Object.ReferenceEquals.
>
> Equals is just a virtual method and behaves as such, so the overridden
>   version will be used (which, for string type compares the contents).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/814880/655293

Comment: Strictly speaking, it never "resolves" to ReferenceEquals - it simply loads the two references and does a "ceq" or "beq" (it doesn't do a "call" to ReferenceEquals)