# Cannot use select in LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a method in which I'm trying to return some database results through a LINQ query, however Visual Studio is not allowing me to use a select statement. This is what I have so far:

```
public static int GetCurrentUserDepartmentId(Guid userGuid)
{
    int departmentId = -1;

    using (PTMS_DataEntities entities = new PTMS_DataEntities())
    {
        var userDepartment = from employee in entities.Employees
                             join user in entities.aspnet_Users
                             on employee.User_Id equals user.UserId
                             where employee.User_Id equals userGuid                                     

        departmentId = (int)userDepartment;                
    }

    return departmentId;
}
```

However, in the LINQ segment, I would *like* it to be as follows:

```
from employee in entities.Employees
join user in entities.aspnet_Users
on employee.User_Id equals user.UserId
where employee.User_Id equals userGuid  
select employee.Department_Id
```

Is there a particular reason why I'm not being allowed to add the last select portion?

Comment: do you mean to say you are not getting the select method in intellisense?

Comment: Correct. When I try to add it manually it doesn't like it, either.

Comment: is the namespace System.Linq is added at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your

```
where employee.User_Id equals userGuid
```

with

```
where employee.User_Id == userGuid
```

Comment: So just to clarify, == and equals work similarly in regular c# code, meaning equals is equivalent to .Equals()? Apologies, I'm somewhat new to using LINQ.

Comment: @Chris V., *equals* is a contextual keyword which is used only in a join clause in a query expression.

Comment: i believe that equals is used only within linq as apart of the join syntax, == and .Equals are a different mechanism, i may be incorrect though

Comment: Ah, okay. So it's only for use in join conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your where clause:

```
var userDepartment = from employee in entities.Employees
                         join user in entities.aspnet_Users
                         on employee.User_Id equals user.UserId
                         where employee.User_Id equals userGuid
```

Should be:

```
var userDepartment = from employee in entities.Employees
                         join user in entities.aspnet_Users
                         on employee.User_Id equals user.UserId
                         where employee.User_Id == userGuid
                         select employee.Department_Id
```

Comment: Isn't == only for use with numerical data though? I was under the impression that Guids are string data

Comment: @ChrisV. The `==` operator can be overloaded for any type.

Comment: @ChrisV. take a look at this [C# difference between `==` and .Equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: @ChrisV == and .Equals can be used to compare value types and reference types.

Comment: **AND**, "equals" is a LINQ keyword that is only used in the `join`.