# c# enum equals() vs ==

Tags: c#, enums, equals

In the case of using enums, is it better to use:

```
if (enumInstance.Equals(MyEnum.SomeValue))
```

or to use

```
if (enumInstance == MyEnum.SomeValue)
```

Are their any important considerations using one vs the other?

Comment: I feel like this has probably been answered before, I just can't find where. If it has been answered let me know and I will deleted this question

Comment: pretty much *every* question asked on SO has been asked here before...  there should be a badge for asking a truly unique question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Comment: There's a small thread about it on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/644790c4-4004-4c66-aa78-b4f64f411beb/enumequals-vs-)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: haha yup... I have one of those too.  :)

Comment: When you call enumInstance.Equals the enum parameter must be boxed as Equals takes object as a parameter, so to avoid the boxing it is better to use ==, if you can

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If the compile-time type of `enumInstance` is the enum type, you're fine with `==`.

If the compile-time type of `enumInstance` is `Enum`, `ValueType` or `Object`, you need to use `Equals`. (You'll get a compile-time error if you try to use `==` in that case.)

Note that your enum currently violates .NET naming conventions - it would normally be `MyEnum.Value`.

Comment: in the case that there is an enum declared that has multiple properties/values set to the same number, does .Equals() convert it to it's numerical representation before comparing? With that, is it against best practices to have multiple enum properties/values have the same underlying numerical value?

Comment: @ToddBFisher: There *is* only a numerical representation. Two names for the same value still actually have the same value. It can be useful in some cases to have multiple names with the same value, but it's rare and should only be used when you really want them to mean the same thing. One example would be if a previous version had a typo in one name, and you wanted to fix the typo without breaking old source code.

Comment: This caused a very sneaky bug, involving a `params Func<T, object>[]` comparison extension method on a generic collection.

Answer (score 35):

Using == instead of Equals is a bit quicker, there is no need to box enums and no functions calls needed here is sample c# code and generated MSIL for it:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var instance = MyEnum.First;

            if (instance == MyEnum.First)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("== Called");
            }

            if (instance.Equals(MyEnum.First))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equals called");
            }

        }     
    }

    enum MyEnum { First = 99, Second = 100}
```

MSIL:

```
IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   99
  IL_0003:  stloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldloc.0
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s   99
  IL_0007:  ceq
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000a:  ceq
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldloc.1
  IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_001d
  IL_0010:  nop
  IL_0011:  ldstr      "== Called"
  IL_0016:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001b:  nop
  IL_001c:  nop
  IL_001d:  ldloc.0
  IL_001e:  box        ConsoleApplication1.MyEnum
  IL_0023:  ldc.i4.s   99
  IL_0025:  box        ConsoleApplication1.MyEnum
  IL_002a:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object)
  IL_002f:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0030:  ceq
  IL_0032:  stloc.1
  IL_0033:  ldloc.1
  IL_0034:  brtrue.s   IL_0043
  IL_0036:  nop
  IL_0037:  ldstr      "Equals called"
  IL_003c:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0041:  nop
  IL_0042:  nop
  IL_0043:  ret
```

As you can see == generates ceq instruction, Equals method performes boxing and callvirt

Comment: If this is your only criterion for choosing this answer, be wary that you may be prematurely optimising chaps!

Answer (score 9):

As an extension to Jon Skeet's old answer, it is true that you get a compilation error when you compare `Enum == YourActualEnum.Value`, however when you do `Enum == Enum`, which compiles fine, it return false all the time.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool TestMethod1()
    {
        bool Result = false;

        Enum l_Value = TEST_ENUM.TEST_VALUE_1;

        Enum l_Check_Value = TEST_ENUM.TEST_VALUE_1;

        Result = l_Value == l_Check_Value;

        return Result;
    }

    public bool TestMethod2()
    {
        bool Result = false;

        TEST_ENUM l_Value = TEST_ENUM.TEST_VALUE_1;

        TEST_ENUM l_Check_Value = TEST_ENUM.TEST_VALUE_1;

        Result = l_Value == l_Check_Value;

        return Result;
    }

    public bool TestMethod3()
    {
        bool Result = false;

        Enum l_Value = TEST_ENUM.TEST_VALUE_1;

        Enum l_Check_Value = TEST_ENUM.TEST_VALUE_1;

        Result = l_Value.Equals(l_Check_Value);

        return Result;
    }

    public enum TEST_ENUM
    {
        TEST_VALUE_1,
        TEST_VALUE_2,
        TEST_VALUE_3
    }
}
```

if you try the following on a test app you'll get the following

```
Console.WriteLine("Method 1 result: {0}", myClass.TestMethod1());

Console.WriteLine("Method 2 result: {0}", myClass.TestMethod2());

Console.WriteLine("Method 3 result: {0}", myClass.TestMethod3());
```

you will get the following results

`Method 1 result: False
Method 2 result: True
Method 3 result: True`

If you wonder why would you ever compare Enum against Enum....I discovered it while trying to be smart while creating an EnumConverter and a FlagConvert for a WPF project. There you receive only an object value as parameter and for the flag converter specifically i wanted to provide a special text for when no flag was selected (i.e. the enum has a value of 0 which has no static member for it).

Nothing else worked (including value.Equals(0), value.Equals((int)0) ) except this:

```
l_Source_Type = value.GetType();

if (l_Source_Type.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute)))
{
    Enum l_Value = (Enum)value;

    Enum l_Check_Value = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(l_Source_Type, 0);

    if (l_Value.Equals(l_Check_Value))
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? As i said I cannot comment and I added this to help other people that have the same issue that I have, as I ended up on this answer while searching to solve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is a case that the other answers here have not mentioned that may help others.

With c# the underlying type of an enum is an integral. Because it is an integral, you can logically OR the enums together.

When using either of the above methods for equality will fail if enums are logically OR'd together.

So for some special cases, such as using enums as flags, you will need to logically AND the case you are testing for with first prior to checking for equality.

```
if ((enumInstance & MyEnum.SomeValue).Equals(MyEnum.SomeValue))
```

or

```
if ((enumInstance & MyEnum.SomeValue) == MyEnum.SomeValue)
```

Strictly speaking it's safest to use "==" with enums.

A complete list of possible enum types can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum