# LINQ issue with Equals statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting an error for the following:

```
var answerList = (from answer in db.QuestionAnswers
                 where answer.tLoginID.Equals(tId) && answer.pLoginID.Equals(pId)
                    && answer.Submitted.Equals(submittedVal)
                select answer).ToList();
```

The error is:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

However, when I change it to:

```
var answerList = (from answer in db.QuestionAnswers
                 where answer.tLoginID.Equals(tId) && answer.pLoginID.Equals(pId)
                select answer).ToList();
```

Then I do this:

```
            answerList.Where(x => x.Submitted.Equals(submittedVal));
```

It works...  What am I missing?  To me these statements are doing the same thing.  But I'm not sure why it is working like this.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out after looking at the link that @SergeyLitvinov provided about `.Equals` that the column I was checking `Submitted` was actually a `Boolean` instead of an `Integer` once I made the types the same my statements worked.  Although I did change it from `.Equals` to `==`.

Comment: why you can't write `answer.tLoginID == tId`?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov - whats the difference?

Comment: Here is a difference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Comment: @Webdad...it looks like Submitted in the erroring code is a key word.  Try encapsulating the Submitted as [Submitted]

Answer (score 2):

The error is from the LINQ to Entities query provider which is attempting to transform your query expression into a SQL statement.  Your second example enumerates your LINQ to Entities query prior to testing for `Submitted.Equals(submittedVal)`, which mean you're using standard LINQ to Objects in local memory (i.e. it is not converted to SQL).