# how to ge personID to delete address before delete person

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Iam trying to delete Addresses that associate to person before when user delete person I have problem  as you see I try to get the person id to delete it from address before delete person 
error

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a
>   constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.
>
> Source Error:

```
   [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        var  address = (from u in db.Addresses
                           where u.PersonID.Equals(id)
                           select u.PersonID).SingleOrDefault();
        db.Addresses.Remove(person);
        db.Persons.Remove(person);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
var  address = (from u in db.Addresses where u.PersonID == id).SingleOrDefault();

if(address != null)
    db.Addresses.Remove(address);

db.Persons.Remove(person);
```

in your example your linq query is pulling data you already have, then you're not using your address variable at all.

You want to remove an address from db.Addresses, not a person.  This also assumes there is only one address per person.

Answer (score 0):

I've only had a quick look but I think your issue lies with the following part of your code:

```
var  address = (from u in db.Addresses
                       where u.PersonID.Equals(id)
                       select u.PersonID).SingleOrDefault();
```

Try replacing

```
where u.PersonID.Equals(id)
```

with

```
where u.PersonID == id
```

Hope this works for you!

(Out of interest, if you check out the following Stackoverflow response from LeakyCode, he has clarified the difference between == and Equals: [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) )

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you want to delete all addresses belonging to a person, you need to get a list of them and remove them...

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);

    var  addresses = from u in db.Addresses
                   where u.PersonID == id;
    addresses.ToList().ForEach(a => db.Addresses.Remove(a));

    db.Persons.Remove(person);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```