# C# List Elements in the Session Not Responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, session

I'm doing a simple program to add a student(with ID,Name) to a List, then to search Student by ID through session.

**Add Student** Module is like below,

```
protected void addStudent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Student> thisstdlist = new List<Student>();
            thisstdlist = (List<Student>)Session["stdlist"];
            thisstdlist.Add(new Student(txtsid.Text,txtsname.Text));
            Session["stdlist"] = thisstdlist;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");


        }
```

**Search Student** Module is Like Below,

```
  protected void searchStudent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            foreach (Student element in (List<Student>)Session["stdlist"])
            {
               if(element.getID().Equals(txtstdid.Text)){
                   txtstdname.Text = element.getName();
               }
           }
        }
```

**Student Class** is like below,

```
public class Student
    {
        private String Name;
        private String ID;

        public Student(String sid, String sn) {

            this.Name = sn;
            this.ID = sid;

        }

        public String getName() {

            return this.Name;
        }
        public String getID()
        {

            return this.ID;
        }


    }
```

But when I added students, for ex: 100,John and Search by 100 it gives me no result. Please can anyone show me the mistake or the correct way of doing this.

Comment: why you are using methods to get your field values ?  you can use auto-implemented properties this is not java.

Comment: How can I do it? Please guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add Student` module won't initialize the student list correctly - you are creating a new `List<Student>` and then throwing the new list away with the next line assignment. I would go with something like:

```
var thisstdlist = (List<Student>)Session["stdlist"];
// If a key isn't found in Session, it will be null ..
if (thisstdlist == null)
{
    // i.e. only re-initialize if it was missing from session
    thisstdlist = new List<Student>();
    // You don't need to continually reassign the session variable
    Session["stdlist"] = thisstdlist;
}
// Adds to the list; now that Session also has a reference to the same list
thisstdlist.Add(new Student(txtsid.Text,txtsname.Text));
```

As per the comment, note that c# has automatic (albeit mutable) properties - you don't need the Java-style getters and setters.

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(string sid, string sn) 
    {
        Name = sn;
        ID = sid;
    }

    public string Name 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Also, in .Net, `==` for strings [is overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) to test values (unlike Java's reference equality for strings), so you can rewrite the comparison as:

```
if (element.ID == txtstdid.Text)
{
    txtstdname.Text = element.Name;
}
```

Re : `foreach` - I guess means that you are using the `List` in a `Dictionary` (HashMap) fashion - if you use `Dictionary` instead of `List` - this will allow you do remove the `foreach` in favour of:

```
// addStudent ...
var txtstdname = new Dictionary<string, Student>();
 // ... 
txtstdname.Add(txtsid.Text, new Student(txtsid.Text,txtsname.Text))

// searchStudent ...
Student element = null;
if (txtstdname.TryGetValue(out element))
{
    txtstdname.Text = element.Name();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

are you setting breakpoints  and actually checking what the values of these lists and what is actually stored in the session?

`.Equals()` is not doing what you think it is

try :

```
 foreach (Student element in (List<Student>)Session["stdlist"])
            {
               if(element.ID == txtstdid.Text){
                   txtstdname.Text = element.getName();
               }
           }
```

Comment: You cannot call element.ID directly since it is private, so I used element.getID(), But Still No Result :(

Comment: sorry, I missed that.  Then make it public , if you have a public function to get it anyways.  OR... just call GetID() ==

Comment: +1. Java style `.Equals` [will still work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) although obviously not a common convention in .Net, but a necessity in Java.