# two seemingly equal variables (values and types are the same) when compared return false

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can this be?

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're currently boxed into `object`, and those two objects are not the same object, which means `==` fails. If you unbox them to `int`, then it will succeed:

```
(int)model.value == (int)model.metadata.Model // true
```

Or you could call `Equals` which should work:

```
model.value.Equals(model.metadata.Model) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

**== Operator**
Only if operands are Value Types and their values are equal, it returns true else false

[`C# difference between`==`and .Equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)