# Comparing strings by == operator in C# - is it a good idea?

Tags: c#, string, comparison, string-comparison

In Java when we use == operator in the context of strings we actually compare references not values (if I understand it correctly).
Because of that it's strongly recommend to use equals method.

Is the situation in C# analogous to Java? Should I avoid comparing strings with == operator?
How to do strings comparsion properly? What is the catch and in what situations I can get something I didn't expect?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Comment: string overloads the == operator [source here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs.html)