# new String() doesn't create new reference object in c#?

Tags: c#

**Edit:**

**Why this question is not duplicate?**
I'm not asking difference between `.Equals()` and `==`. I'm asking how does actually `==` work. I mean, when I created strings using different method, I should have seen different result. But I see same result.

I was looking into `==` operator in c#. To my surprise it gave same result for following codes (contrary to JAVA). But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals), `==` is for reference check and I should see different result for my code then why do I see same result for both of them? Shouldn't I see different results for my piece of codes? Is it because `new String()` in c# doesn't generate new reference?

```
 String s = "abc";
 String s1 = "abc";
 Console.WriteLine("Expected output: True, Actual output: " + (s1==s).ToString());
```

**Output**

> Expected output: **True**, Actual output: **True**

Another code check

```
    String s2 = new String("abc".ToCharArray());
    String s3 = new String("abc".ToCharArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Expected output: False, Actual output: " + (s2 == s3).ToString());
```

**Output**

> Expected output: **False**, Actual output: **True**

**Note:** I understand difference reference & value check. I've tried result with `ReferenceEquals` and it shows expected result to me.

Comment: If duplicate does not cover your problem make sure to check results of search http://www.bing.com/search?q=java+c%23+string+equals to see if there is better duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've edited my question to show, why it is not a duplicate of other SO question. Please look into it :)

Comment: @Abhishek - In both cases you create the string `"abc"`, and compare `"abc"=="abc"`. Why are you expecting `False` on the second example?

Comment: @Kobi I created new object by specifying `new String()`. That is how it works in JAVA. But as Nikhil pointed out, `==` are overloaded I would see same result. :)

Comment: Sure... also questions that have immediate answer in documentation are ... not exactly the best once - [C# string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) "Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references. This makes testing for string equality more intuitive"

Comment: Thanks, got it. There were many iterations on this question, I might have missed a step.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yup, got to know about it from Nikhil's answer. I wasn't aware of `==` being overloaded in c#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally for reference types `==` operator do check for reference equality.

String is also a reference type but in String class `==` operator is overloaded to check for content equality and not reference equality.

It says and I quote

`Determines whether two specified strings have the same value.`

Read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx

FYI, in string  `!=` operator is also oveloaded to check for string content inequality.

Comment: Awesome. Got it! Never knew, that `==` is overloaded in c#.

Comment: Yup, I tried it. But it shows wait for few minutes before marking it as answer. :) Give me some time

Answer (score 1):

In c# operator `==` for string compares value, not reference.