# .Net, C# - Boolean.Equal differs from == compare

Tags: c#, automapper, equals, boolean-operations

We are using [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) to map from IDataReader to List of Entities.

One Problem that i noticed while unit testing was the following. If we read an bool value from database (bit), AutoMapper does verry fine. But when we us FluentAssertions for UnitTesting there is a problem with the ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo function. It says True expected but True returned on the bool property of the entity.

So i tried to check the bool properties and noticed that `expected == returnd` works (returns `true`) but `expected.Equals(returned)` does not work (returns `false`)?!

I thought `==` and `equals` should be almost the same for bool type?

What could cause this strange behaviour?

Here some code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("server=someServer;user id=someUser;password=***;database=someDatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    var itemsBefore = new List<Item> { new Item { CheckDispo = true } };

    command.CommandText = "SELECT CheckDispo FROM Items WHERE ItemId = 1814";
    var itemsAfter = Mapper.DynamicMap<List<Item>>(command.ExecuteReader());

    var a = itemsAfter[0].CheckDispo.Equals(true); // false
    var b = itemsAfter[0].CheckDispo == true; // true
}

public class Item
{
    public bool CheckDispo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's because `Equals` checks for the type too, since they are different the output is different

Comment: Why are they different?  I CheckDispo is bool and true is bool too?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess `Equals` checks for object equality, while the `==` checks for the values equality

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# difference between \`==\` and .Equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: Okay but maybe you can have a look at my question.. I am comparing bool! This is a value Type. When i instantiate Item and call equals on CheckDispo then everything works...

Comment: @ragerory This isn't java `bool` is just an alias for `Boolean` and `Boolean` is a value type.

Comment: `Boolean` and `bool` are **not** different. You are confusing Java and C#. In C#, `bool` is just an alias for `System.Boolean`, which is a struct, not a class.

Comment: Ugh. I've been going back and forth too much. You guys are right. My mind was in Java.

Comment: @psoshmo In that question it's comparing an `object` to a `string`.  Here the types are both `bool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this late edit, but I have found what has gone wrong. We read the property out of our database and our 'boolean' is represented by -1 not 1.
Automapper uses dynamically generated IL code to read from a datareader and because they do this, automapper is able to write -1 to the bool field. This results in a value of 0xff in out RAM.
If we now look at the il code for the equals method then we understand wy `.equal` is not `==`.

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance bool  Equals(bool obj) cil managed
{
  .custom instance void __DynamicallyInvokableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldind.u1
  IL_0002:  ldarg.1
  IL_0003:  ceq
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Boolean::Equals
```

This loads an 1 and our value to the stack and compares both. Due to the fact that in our RAM the bool is -1 (0xFF) the comparison will return false.

See also this item on [github.com](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data/issues/12) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Both results should return true. 
I have tested your same scenario above and it does return true in both cases. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

The boolean class overrides the Equals method as follows:

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj as bool))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return this == (bool)obj;
        }
```

It also provides a separate overloaded method which accepts a boolean as a parameter. This just uses the equality operator. I think this was added because it provides better performance over the Equals method because it avoids the  typecasting overhead.

```
public bool Equals(bool obj)
        {
            return this == obj;
        }
```

In your case since you are passing a boolean it should hit the above overloaded method and as you can see, it is just using the === operator.

Comment: I would suggest that you try the above code in a simple Console application to check what results you receive. When I encounter similar strange behaviours, I usually try to extract things as a separate simplified project because it is easier to troubleshoot and debug.

Comment: @  ragerory. I am casting to make sure that the result is of type 'bit' to mimic the question's scenario

Comment: Okey your right, the bool in our company is representated by smallint -1, when im casting the -1 to bit the equal works, if i dont do that AutoMapper sets CheckDispo to true but the equal dont work, i dont know why...
Casting will solve my Problem THANKS!!