# Unity3D Boomlagoon JSON string compare

Tags: json, if-statement, unity-game-engine, unityscript, variable-types

I am using Unity3D with Boomlagoon JSON from Unity asset store. I am sending a json from server and then extracting a string from that and comparing it with another string in an if statement. I cannot for the death of me make it work.

```
var reply : String = WebSocketSingleton.getInstance().RecvString();

Debug.Log ("Received: " + reply);

var jsonReply = JSONObject.Parse(reply);

Debug.Log("jsonReply['event']: " + jsonReply["event"].ToString());
Debug.Log("jsonReply['event'] type : " + jsonReply["event"].ToString().GetType());
Debug.Log("login type: " + "login".GetType());

if (jsonReply["event"].ToString() == "login") {
    Debug.Log("check");
} else {
    Debug.Log("fail");
}
```

It keeps going to else.

Console log:

```
Received: {"event":"login","email":"asdf@"}

jsonReply['event']: "login"

jsonReply['event'] type : System.String

login type: System.String

fail
```

Unity package I am using for json: `https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5788`

I hope I'm not just being a massive idiot...

Comment: try using `String.CompareTo()` method instead of `==` operator

Comment: Okay that worked, but I would still like an explanation why `==` doesn't. Also why does `Debug.Log(jsonReply["event"].ToString().CompareTo("login"));` return `-1` and then the check after it passes as if it returned true. I am so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `==` doesn't work for strings.

Check [This Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-compare) for help.

Reference: [Difference Between == and string.Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814878/4366237)