# Condition not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

It doesn't work:-

```
if(keyval.Value == "menu") // false
```

but this works:-

```
if(keyval.Value.ToString() == "menu") // true
```

what is the difference between these two.

why the first condition isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by _not works_? You get any compiler time error? What is the type of `Value`? Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# difference between \`==\` and .Equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: condition false but  keyval.Value is "menu"

Comment: is `Value` a string?

Comment: yes keyval.Value = "menu"

Comment: prakash, that isn't what I asked, what *type* is `Value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, `keyval.Value` has a type of `object`. That means that instead of comparing the two strings by value, you are comparing them by reference - and it's perfectly valid for two strings with the same value to be a different instance.

The proper way to do the comparison would be

```
if((string)keyval.Value == "menu")
```

if the values are always strings. Or just avoid storing `string`s as `object`s :)