# Won't exit while loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

As intended when I type 1, 2, or 3, it is supposed to exit out of the loop or not enter it. But if I write something other than those 3 numbers it is supposed to loop until I type 1, 2, or 3.

But for some reason I can't get it to not enter the loop or to exit it. It doesn't matter what I type even if it is the right number to not enter the loop 1, 2, or 3. It still does enter it and loop regardless.

```
string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
string message = "";

Console.WriteLine("Card 1, 2, or, 3?");
Console.ReadLine();


while (userValue != "1" || userValue != "2" || userValue != "3")
{
    message = "try again. Card 1, 2, or, 3?";
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

if (userValue == "1")
{
    message = "You win a Coke";
}
else if (userValue == "2")
{
    message = "You win a Diet Coke";
}
else if (userValue == "3")
{
    message = "You win a Apple Juice";
}
Console.WriteLine(message);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @DrewKennedy, why would you use `Equals()`, rather than `==` to compare strings?

Comment: @DavidArno In Java that would be the proper way to do it, which I assume is what spawned that comment. Since this is not Java, however, `==` is just fine.

Comment: Before starting a war on `==` versus `Equals()` for string comparison, how about [some light reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals).  The battle is being fought elsewhere...

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot More or less, yeah. In C# they offer the same functionality, with hidden caveats for each idea. For some reason I thought `==` was problematic, which was my Java thinking.

Comment: This is a perfect candidate for solving via debugging. That is what you should do when you have code that runs but doesn't behave as expected. Go line by line and look at what the values are doing. In this case you would have noticed that `userValue` is never being assigned and then you would have noticed that the condition on the while loop is wrong. Debugging is one of the most important skills you will learn as a developer, and you can't always rely on SO to do the debugging for you

Comment: Vote to close, typo, the equals and position of Readline inside the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign `Console.ReadLine()` each time, both inside the loop and on the way into it.

`userValue = Console.ReadLine();`

But you have bigger issues than that, as `userValue != "1" || userValue != "2" || userValue != "3"` will always be true.

I think you mean `userValue != "1" && userValue != "2" && userValue != "3"`

I.e.

```
        string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
        string message = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Card 1, 2, or, 3?");
        userValue = Console.ReadLine(); // Assign

        while (userValue != "1" && userValue != "2" && userValue != "3")
        {
            message = "try again. Card 1, 2, or, 3?";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            userValue = Console.ReadLine(); // Assign
        }

        if (userValue == "1")
        {
            message = "You win a Coke";
        }
        else if (userValue == "2")
        {
            message = "You win a Diet Coke";
        }
        else if (userValue == "3")
        {
            message = "You win a Apple Juice";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

See MSDN on [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) for more example usage.

Answer (score 7):

You need to assign the `userValue` inside your while loop as well.

EDIT: needed to switch your `||`s to `&&` as well - the value will ALWAYS not be one of the 3 values ;)

EDIT 2: you also needed to add the assignment before your while loop, as well.  Thanks @Nikolai

```
while (userValue != "1" && userValue != "2" && userValue != "3")
{
    message = "try again. Card 1, 2, or, 3?";
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    // vvvvvv is missing
    userValue = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In other news, have you heard of the [do..while loop?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)