# How can I get case insensitive list in MVC using search string?

Tags: c#

Below is the Action Method Index of my Home Controller that fetch the data from SQL Server database view named AllMovies.

```
using Skylink.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;


namespace Skylink.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
        {
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        MovieContext movieContext = new MovieContext();
        var movies = from m in movieContext.Movies1.ToList()
                         select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                movies = movies.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
                break;
            case "date":
                movies = movies.OrderBy(s => s.Print);
                break;
            default:
                movies = movies.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateAdd);
                break;

        }

        int pageSize = 24;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(movies.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

    }
```

And below is the cshtml of the Index view (Razor) that the above action result returns.

```
@using Skylink.Models;

@model PagedList.IPagedList<Skylink.Models.Movie1>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{ViewBag.Title = "Recently Added";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/StyleSheet4.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <br />
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of    @Model.PageCount

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))

{
    <p>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}

    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="img">

        <a href="@Url.Action("Details","Home", new { id = item.Id })"><img src="@Url.Content(@item.ImageUrl)" alt="Image Not Available" /></a>
        <div class="desc" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:x-small;  color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Title)</div>
        <div class="desc" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small; color:yellow">IMDB: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Rating)</div>
        <div class="desc" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small; color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Print)</div>
        </div>

}
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working fine but the search string at runtime didn't match the case for example I have a movie name "Ted" but when I type "ted" in search textbox I get no results. I have to type exactly "Ted" to find the movie. All I need is to type "ted" and get the result.

Hope I explained my Question in detail.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have edited my question with some more details, kindly have a look and recommend the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, it really helped.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`ToLower`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx) for your comparisons?

```
switch (sortOrder.ToLower()) {
    case "name_desc":
        movies =  movies.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
        break;
    case "date":
        movies = movies.OrderBy(s => s.Print);
        break;
    default:
        movies = movies.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateAdd);
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

BTW, using `==` for string equality assessments is *bad*. It's checking for reference equality, not lexical equality. You need to use [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) answer for why.

**Edit** since OP clarified the question... if this is the line you're having issues with:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)
                           || s.Title.Contains(searchString));
}
```

(btw, that `||` clause is checking the same condition twice!!) ...here's the suggested fix:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.IndexOf(searchString, 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);
}
```

Comment: Note that here, `case "date_desc":` is useless since it does the same as default

Comment: @Khurram glad I could help. Please consider marking this the answer