# Why i keep see null or "" items in the array?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
if (text != "" || text != null)
                    myList[i] = text;
```

myList is string array
But in the end of the loop i keep see in myList items that are "" or null.

```
WindowSnap[] windowsarray = WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray();
            this.listBoxSnap.BeginUpdate();
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();           
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(windowsarray);
            string[] myList = new string[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
            for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();

                int first = tt.IndexOf("Text: ");
                int second = tt.IndexOf(",", first + 6);
                string text = tt.Substring(first + 6, second - first - 6);
                if (text != "" || text != null)
                    myList[i] = text;
            }
```

I tried inside the loop and after the loop the line:

```
myList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

But still there are items with ""

Comment: If you don't want to put an empty string or null into the array, use &&, not ||. Better yet, use !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value).

Comment: It would also be better to reverse it and use the `.Equals()` method.
`if (!text.Equals(null) && !text.Equals(string.empty))`

Comment: @Draken Why would `Equals` be better?  Both end up doing the exact same thing.

Comment: You might want to use a `List<string>` instead.  When you initialize the `string[]` it going to be populated with nulls.

Comment: @juharr [See here for why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/814881/833070)

Comment: @Draken But `text` is a `string` reference as is `""`, so you don't have the issue of something like `text == ((object)"")`.  And the `null` check is going to be a reference check anyway.  And hopefully you don't expect someone to refactor the code to change `string` variables to `object`.

Comment: You don't assign `myList[i] = text` if text is empty *but* you change `i` in the loop. Use `List<string> myList` and `myList.Add(text);` instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention that after parsing the text of the items inside the loop i want to update the items text in the listBox already. Not to add new items of myList so maybe it's better to work directly with the listBox items somehow. What i want is to parse only the items(that already exist in the listBox) text in the listBox. Update i mean change/replace but only the text !!! with the text of each item in the listBox.

Comment: Related to [Why getting all the items in listBox null when trying to remove part of each item text?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37279631/719186)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing

```
if(text != "" || text != null)
```

Do

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
```

The OR in your condition is wrong. It should be AND.

Also note that it would be better if you use `List<string>` instead of `String[]`. Arrays are fixed size, so you'll still get null values in your output for the items that are skipped by the above condition. A List on the other hand can be grown one by one when needed. So your code would look like:

```
WindowSnap[] windowsarray = WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray();
this.listBoxSnap.BeginUpdate();
this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();           
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(windowsarray);

List<string> myList = new List<string>();
for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
   int first = tt.IndexOf("Text: ");
   int second = tt.IndexOf(",", first + 6);
   string text = tt.Substring(first + 6, second - first - 6);
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
       myList.Add(text);
}
```

If you are a fan of LINQ, you may do it like this:

```
string[] mylist = (from tt in listBoxSnap.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString())
           let first = tt.IndexOf("Text: ")
           let second = tt.IndexOf(",", first + 6)
           let text = tt.Substring(first + 6, second - first - 6)
           where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
           select text).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Note that I'm `Cast`ing `Items` collection to `object`. If you know the actual type of the items in listBoxSnap, you may want to cast it to that type.

Comment: He doesn't want to remove things from the original array as per OP.

Comment: Ah you mean the output array, not the original array. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention that after making/creating the myList array i don't want to add this array as items to the listBox i want to change the existing items already in the listBox text only. Maybe i should now use the myList array variable at all and working directly with the windowsarray or better directly with the listBox items already added. What i want is to remove some of the text of each item. i did it with the indexof and the substring but how do i update now the items text in the listBox ?

Comment: @DanielLipman: What is `WindowSnap`? Note that you're using `ToString()` against its items to populate you `ListBox`, which returns a **value that has no link with the original `WindowSnap` object**. If `WindowSnap` has a public property that returns its name, a much better way is to use binding. You can then get access to the original WindowSnap object from within ListBox item and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this line:

```
string[] myList = new string[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
```

creates a string array with **as many elements as your `listBoxSnap.Items`**. All these elements are initialized to `null`. So the `null` elements **are there from the beginning**.

Second, in your loop you set the elements `if (text != "" || text != null)`. This is `true` for all `text`s, because `||` means **OR**. So either it is null (so it's not `""`) or it is not null (so it's true too).

So you better make this array a `List`:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

and in your loop you do:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) myList.Add(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (text != ""  ||  text != null)
    myList[i] = text;
```

This reminds me of a moral tale about programming that I heard during my college years. The story (supposedly true) goes that a young programmer was working on a financial program which had a rule that applied an exemption for people under 18 and over 65. So to implement this rule, the programmer wrote code like this:

```
if (age < 18  and  age > 65)
    exempt = true;
```

Needless to say, his co-workers eventually noticed the flaw in his code and tried to explain it to him, but he was adamant that he was implementing the rule *exactly* as it was stated in the requirements: exemptions are for customers under 18 *and* customers over 65. He did not see why he needed to use *or* in his conditional test.

**Moral**

For (the hopefully few of) those of you who do not see what the problem is, the test should be this:

```
if (text != ""  &&  text != null)
    myList[i] = text;
```

If you still don't see it, ask yourself what happens when `text` is `null`.