# C# Tuple Equality vs Contains in list

Tags: c#, tuples

I recently encountered some surprising behaviour of a Tuple in a List. It seems that Contains in a list does a different comparison than what I was expecting. Please can someone explain the difference?

```
Tuple<int,int> A = new Tuple<int, int>(5,5);
Tuple<int, int> B = new Tuple<int, int>(5, 5);
List<Tuple<int,int>> AList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() {A};

bool C = AList.Contains(B); // returns true
bool D = A == B; // returns false
```

Edit 1: To address the duplicate flag. I was aware that == and .Equals were different functions, the surprising thing here is the particular implementation in the List.Contains function.

Comment: The list is calling `.Equals()` as the comparison, rather than `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A == B compares references and since they point to two different objects the result is false. I assume this was already familiar to you.

bool C = AList.Contains(B); will call .Equal which checks for equality thus returning true.

The difference is the same as A == B vs A.Equals(B)

Answer (score 3):

Tuples are implemented as reference types, for more info please [read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx).

The baseline is that for reference type `==` performs an identity comparison, therefore the result will be true only if both references are pointing to the same object.

The `Equals` method performs a value comparison and it will return true if the references point to objects that are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` uses the `Equals` method inherited from `object`

`==` tests for instance equality (ie, are they references to the same exact instance).

Therefore, we can summise that `Tuple` must override `Equals` and return true if each of the elements match, whereas `==` must check that the instances on the left and right hand side are the same.

Answer (score 1):

That was curious so I took a look as well. When you try

```
bool D = A.Equals(B);
```

It returns `true` which made me to look at [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful :)