# How to properly use C# Linq to get a filtered list?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Say for example I have C# LINQ query as below:

```
var allBooks = from book in books
               select book;
var booksNonFiction = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genre = NonFiction)
```

In this example, I want to obtain all the `NonFiction` titles in `allBooks` collection. Am a bit unsure about the lambda expression.

Comment: Just try `.OrderBy()` :) *Edit: Maybe I should have read the question before :p

Comment: I'm also unsure about that expression.  Should be double `=` -- `Genre == Nonfiction`

Comment: What type does `Genre` return?

Comment: Your title and question differ quite a bit. The title asks how to order, the question asks how to filter the data. Please [edit] your question to update one or the other such that they match.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan, I added more detail.

Comment: There still is no ordering going on.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman, further made more edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the way how to think in lambda expression it helped me a lot to translate the "x =>" into "every x in the sequence"

In your example AllBooks is a sequence of books. So your statement:

```
var booksNonFiction = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genre == NonFiction)
```

would translate into: "From the sequence of all books, take "every book where book.genre equals nonfiction"

If you have more difficult linq statements it helps if you use plural nouns for your sequences (collections), and singular nouns for the parameters of the lambda expression (where you used x). This helps you remember the thing every x means.

var nonFictionBooks = allBooks.Where(book => book.Genre == NonFiction)

Here you can see that book is one element of the collection allBooks.

```
var frontPages = allBooks.Where(book => book.Genre == NonFiction)
    .Select(book => book.FirstPage)
```

Even though you might not now the Select statement yet, you can understand that it means that from every "book" in the collection of allBooks, you should take book.FirstPage.

To help understand the possibilities of Linq the article [The Standard Linq operators](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx) helped me to learn the most used Linq statements

Linq heavily leans on extension methods. If you are not familiar with this, the following might help: [Extension Methods Demystified](http://www.blackrabbitcoder.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the allbooks linq and this contains the same collection as books.

```
var booksNonFiction = books.Where(x => x.Genre == "NonFiction");
```

And if you want to order the data

```
var booksNonFiction = books.Where(x => x.Genre == "NonFiction").OrderBy(b => b.Title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a double =:

```
Where(x => x.Genre **==** NonFiction)
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need first stement, because it says: enumerate all books and return them.
And also need method that actually enumerates collection, without it, it remains just a query.

```
var booksNonFiction = books.Where(x => x.Genre == NonFiction).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If Genre is Enum:

```
var booksNonFiction = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genre.Equals(Genre.NonFiction));
```

2.If Genre is a string:

```
var booksNonFiction = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genre.Equals("NonFiction"));
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `.Equals()` in C# because of [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/814880/2113548) (unless handling with `null` values). Rom may have a Java background where `==` and `.Equals()` function differently. This can be seen in [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/2113548) with supported answers below.

Comment: Interesting thought, I was wondering what the case would be for a string.

Comment: When Genre is a `string`, the `.Equals()` is actually harmful because it will throw when Genre is null. For an `enum` it is just less readable.