# What is the difference between string == "something" or string.Equals("something")

Tags: c#, .net, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

In C# I have a problem in my code, when i try to write

```
if (string == "text") return string;
```

it does not give correct answer 
but
when i try to write`

```
if(string.Equals("text")) return string;
```

it gives me the correct answer. 
my question is what problem is here, what is the main difference between   string == "something" or string.Equals("something") for string matching.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Comment: take a look : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1135937/Story-of-Equality-in-Net-Part

Comment: tnx buddy .. that what i wanted to know :D :D