# How to find string in Dictionary list and get its pair integer value

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, dictionary

I'm trying to find string in dictionary with pair values to find its integer value. Important to find through the string and then get its integer, not vice-versa. 1000 strings list "string" and integer:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

and now I want find  specific string, some input, which is exist in Dict:

```
 string findStr = "hello world";
```

This way I got all strings which start with "hello...":

```
 var result = Dict.Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith(findStr) && pair.Value > 0);
```

and this way just nothing:

```
var result = Dict.Where(pair => pair.Key.Equals(findStr) && pair.Value > 0);
```

I'm not sure how to go further to get desired result:

To find equal string  in my Dictionary and get its pair integer value.

Comment: did you tried `pair.Key == findStr`

Comment: Just use Dictionary's TryGetValue: `Dict.TryGetValue(findStr, out intValue)`, it returns a bool

Comment: Or you can also lower the case and trim white spaces at the start and end of string.

Comment: @o_weisman  yes I think this way I got correct results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be reading a `dictionary` like this `dict[key]`, which will give you `O(1)` access. You can either check if the `key` exists first either by using `ContainsKey(key)` method or try to read the value by `TryGetValue`

Comment: TryGetValue Hello, I'm going to mark it as answer, TryGetValue works well

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Dict.Where(pair => pair.Key==findStr && pair.Value > 0);
```

see the difference between .equals and == here 
[C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: hello, this way also  should work for sure, but in my case I got 0 in result if I use it in followed condition, but with event for example it works well. So I'm going to mark AD.Net answer as TryGetValue is more useful for my case, but this answer is also good and useful for different case

Comment: Using `.Where` will give you very poor performance with a dictionary, when you use that you now have the performance as if you had a `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` which is much slower than a dictionary.