# Variable retrieved from json data doesn't seem right

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, database

I retrieve data from mysql server and one of the fields is an int value
(1 or 0 ) and it's printed right (1 or zero ) but when I try to apply an if condition on this variable for example :

```
 if (currentCourse.getForFreeStr() !=0)forFree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 the condition always give the result for != 0
```

I also tried to take the value as a String and put make the condition :

```
  if (currentCourse.getForFreeStr() !="0")forFree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it does the same please tell me what is wrong .
note : when I use the same codes on the data retrieved from a similar table in another database it works fine !

Comment: post your json data and CurrentCourse model class

Comment: try using if (!currentCourse.getForFreeStr().Equals("0")) to compare the contents of the strings rather than comparing references. For more information on this see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Comment: Thanks for your answers I will try it and tell you if it worked