# How to set if condition attribute Name bool in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have some simple code to check if data exist in entity, when I save new data with `isoverdue = true` and data exists, it will show alert that data exists.

```
private string _entityname = "tss_rating";

QueryExpression Query = new QueryExpression(_entityname);  
Query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
Query.Criteria.AddCondition("tss_isoverdue", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);

EntityCollection Items = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(Query);

if (Items.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    Entity entity = new Entity(_entityname);

    if (entity.Contains("tss_isoverdue") && entity.Attributes["tss_isoverdue"].Equals(true))   // this if condition cannot be fire when input data
    {
        throw new Exception("IsOverdue with Yes Value is Exist....cannot create same data...!");
    }
}
```

Need suggestions.

**UPDATE CODE AND IT WORKED:**

```
public void Form_OnCreate_PreOperation(IOrganizationService organizationService, IPluginExecutionContext pluginExceptionContext, Entity CurrentEntity)
        {
            try
            {
                QueryExpression Query = new QueryExpression(pluginExceptionContext.PrimaryEntityName);  
                Query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
                Query.Criteria.AddCondition("tss_isoverdue", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);

                EntityCollection Items = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(Query);
                if (Items.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (CurrentEntity.Contains("tss_isoverdue"))
                    {
                        if ((bool)CurrentEntity.Attributes["tss_isoverdue"] == true)
                            throw new Exception("IsOverdue with Yes Value is Exist....cannot create same data...!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(_classname + ".Form_OnCreate_PreOperation: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

I think you are trying to: Make a function that will throw an error if it finds a `tss_rating` record, where `tss_isoverdue` is `true`.

I'm going to guess this isn't working.

I think the problem is here: `Entity entity = new Entity(_entityname);`

You are making a new `Entity` object which won't have any attributes, which means `entity.Contains("tss_isoverdue")` will return false.

So your `if` condition will never be true.

You should either;

Use an `Entity` object from the returned collection, e.g. `Items.Entities.First()`.

Simplify your code to this. You don't need to check the `Entity` object `tss_isoverdue` value again, as you have already done that in your query. Knowing that at least one record was returned means at least one record has `tss_isoverdue` is `true`

```
EntityCollection Items = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(Query);

if (Items.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    throw new Exception("IsOverdue with Yes Value is Exist....cannot create same data...!");
}
```

A side point, you [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) want to use `entity.Attributes["tss_isoverdue"] == true`, rather than `entity.Attributes["tss_isoverdue"].Equals(true)`.