# When 3 != 3 in c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

[image]

Above is a partial screen shot from Visual Studio 2015 while debugging some c# code.  CachedList[2][uniqueColumn.Name] is an int and its value is 3, value is also an in and its value is also 3, however when I compare the two I get the wrong result.  How can this be?

Comment: Because they are boxed as `object` you're getting reference comparison and not value comparison.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Comment: Yes that is the solution.  I need to use .Equals() rather than ==.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that the integers are boxed ('wrapped' in objects), and the compare for objects does a compare-by-reference: are they the *same object in memory*, answer: no.

If you want to compare them by value, and you know that both are always `int` (and you want to make this explicit in your code), then you can use typecasting to unbox and `==` to compare:

```
var isEqual = (int)CachedList[2][uniqueColumn.Name] == (int)value;
```

(see .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z3lwBG)

If the type *inside* the two objects isn't always `int`, but you know or assume they are the exact same type, then you can use `.Equals()`:

```
var isEqual = CachedList[2][uniqueColumn.Name].Equals(value);
```

Note, this may still not always give the desired result. If one is a boxed `int` and the other is e.g. a boxed `long`, then - *because* the types are different - `Equals()` will return `false`, even if the values themselves might be considered equal, as in `(object)3` vs `(object)3L`. `Equals()` does not even try to compare the values in such a case.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning `.Equals`

Comment: Actually gunnerone has the solution that works for me.  I don't want to cast to an int because the code must also handle string, long, DateTime, etc.  So I'm using object1.Equals(object2) rather than object1 == object2.

Comment: Included .Equals and how it behaves.