# Implement Method of Object Class => public virtual bool Equals(obj);

Tags: c#, object, c#-3.0

We Have to implement the method of object class => public virtual bool Equals(obj); 
without using Equals or Reference Equals Method.
It has to work same as virtual Equals Method.

I **can** use `objA == objB`.

Comment: _"without using ... Reference Equals"_ - why can't you use ReferenceEquals? _"It has to work same as virtual Equals Method."_ - why do you need to implement it then?

Comment: It is an assignment given to us that ..we should implement a method that works same as virtual Equals Method ..without using Equals or Ref Equals.@John

Comment: Can you use the `.Equals()` method of an object that you're testing?

Comment: We should not Equals anywhere in the program@john

Comment: Please provide the **full text** of your assessment question, so we have more context.

Comment: Assignment :
    Implement following methods of Object class 
a. public virtual bool Equals(obj); 
b. public static bool Equals(objA, objB); 
c. public static bool ReferenceEquals(objA, objB);

Note: Make sure to follow coding standards. @mjwills

Comment: Where does that say without using Equals or Reference Equals Method?                we asked our trainer..so they said we cannot.And,We should implement the methods of object class..not,in object class.@mjwills

Comment: For Example.I implemented for Reference Equals as:public class ReferenceEqualsClass
{
    public static bool ReferenceEqMethod(Object obj1, Object obj2)
    {
        return obj1 == obj2;
    }
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static Equals Method Returning False for Value Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097503/static-equals-method-returning-false-for-value-types)

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a code answer, since this is an assignment after all.

Things you want to check:

1. Null - are both objects null? Is one object null and the other isn't?

   `object.ReferenceEquals(objA, null)` is the old preferable way (since it doesn't potentially use an overriden `Equals` implementation as `==` would. With C# 7+, you can also use `if (objA is null)`.
2. You can now compare `if (objA == objB)`. Note that it's here where `objA.Equals(objB)` would be used, but since that's not allowed, I guess we can use `==`.

There is also `objA.GetHashCode()` which indicates the *potential* for equality. I say "potential" because it's possible for two very different objects to have the same hash code. If two objects are equal (and correctly implemented) then they should have the same hash code. In short: you can rely on `GetHashCode()` to indicate the possibility of equality, but you need to do another check (2) to be sure.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden) for more on the relationship between `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`.
And see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814880/3181933) for more information about `==` vs `Equals()`