# static Equals Method Returning False for Value Types

Tags: c#

```
 public static bool EqualsMethod(**ValueType** value1, **ValueType** value2)
        {
            bool result = false;
            Type t1 = value1.GetType();
            Type t2 = value2.GetType();
            var i = (**dynamic**)value1;
            var j = (**dynamic**)value2;
        }
```

Can Anyone Please Tell me **instead of dynamic**. What Can I Use **For Unboxing ?**. So that it **can unbox any primitive datatype**. And I **should not Use Equals Keyword** anywhere in my code. I  can use  the **comparer technique** , But It is not working

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? As in, value types where this fails?

Comment: int i=12 and int j=12.   When I pass them to equals method ..   as both the values are equal, ..   it should return true.    But It is returning False.@john

Comment: You might want to amend your example because you've put "// True" next to the `Console.WriteLine` in your example. Also, your example `Main()` method outputs `true` for me.

Comment: Ya It is returning True...  But I used a dynamic Keyword in my code...   So instead of using dynamic  , I want to use another keyword or anyother process.Please Help@john

Comment: Use `Comparer.Default.Compare(value1, value2) == 0` to compare instead of your whole method. I know that that is not *exactly* the same for all cases, but for built-in value types it should be.

Comment: Did you read the doc for `ValueType`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This answer generates a lambda to evaluate the expression, since there's some arbitrary limitation on what you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39305455/149436

Answer (score 2):

Equality for primitive types (native to the CLR, like `int`) is implemented with CIL instructions. The default equality for value types is done [by reflection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,d8b9b308e644b983) (which is why struct types should provide their own equality).

`System.ValueType` is a reference type, in order for it to work as a base type for other types. Thus, any struct you pass to a `ValueType` parameter is boxed, and calling the `==` operator on them does a reference comparison, as you've noticed.

If you want to pass in structs without boxing, you can use generics and the `where T : struct` constraint.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a really helpful answer. But I dont want to pass in structs   and want to use class only without using generics. so, Instead of  System.ValueType what should I use  ?. @jan.h

Comment: You could use the Equals() method of `ValueType` (i.e. something similar to `value1.Equals(value2)`). That will determine value equality instead of reference equality.

Comment: No We Should not at all use Equals or Reference Equals Methods.  Thats where the problem is..    Just  here   public static bool EqualsMethod(ValueType value1, ValueType value2)    instead  of  valuetype  keyword  what  shoud  i  use,  so that it  will   accept  all  primitive  types .   @jan.h

Comment: Then write your own reflection-based equality method. It's not terribly difficult, even with the public reflection API. But at some point you'll probably need to use Equals.

Comment: But I am beginner , So I don't know  how  to   use   Reflections..Please help me out @jan.h

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jan.h's answer, I would suggest using:

```
public static bool EqualsMethod<T>(T value1, T value2) where T: struct
{
    return value1.Equals(value2);
}
```

as a starting point. By constraining to value types (`T: struct`) then this should meet your requirements.

Comment: This is *OK*, but it will *always* box `value2`, even if it can resolve that it can use static-call for the `value1.Equals`. It *may* also bo\x `value1` if that isn't the case. There's a much better approach (see my answer).

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use *ToString()* method from object class, rather than unboxing and storing it in another variable.
eg: value1.ToString() && value2.ToString()

Comment: That's not great; `ToString()` is expensive, and is not necessarily at all related to conceptual equality

Comment: but we can directly compare the content by using ToString() rather than unboxing. @Marc Gravell

Comment: unboxing is usually free (in terms of allocations - it is *boxing* that is expensive); `ToString()` is not; also, you have *no clue* what `ToString()` is going to return in the general case - there is no requirement *whatsoever* for `ToString()` to have equality semantics

Answer (score 0):

`EqualityComparer<T>` already has you covered:

```
public static bool EqualsMethod<T>(T value1, T value2)
    => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value1, value2);
```

By using generics, this works for any `T` - and in the case of value-type `T`, it will work without boxing or unboxing. The implementation of `.Default` here is clever, and has separate implementations for:

- reference types
- naked value types
- `Nullable<T>` value types

with each implementation doing "the right thing". It also makes use of the `IEquatable<T>` interface where supported, dropping to `.Equals(object)` as a fallback.

So: it should do the right thing in all relevant cases. For your own value-types: be sure to implement `IEquatable<T>`.

If you want to restrict it to *just* value-types, add a `where T : struct` clause, but ... that doesn't seem necessary or useful here.