# Why I can not delete row in Excel?

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I use [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) to delete only one row with index 10 using this code:

```
using (var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
   var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
   ws.DeleteRow(10, 1);
}
```

When I save output file I see that row is exist in file:

```
p.SaveAs(new FileInfo("c:\\output.xlsx"));
```

Why row is not deleted?

My full code is:

```
  using(var p = new ExcelPackage(fi)) {

   var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
   var start = ws.Dimension.Start;
   var end = ws.Dimension.End;

   for (int row = start.Row + 1; row <= end.Row; row++) {
    for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++) {

     var value = ws.Cells[row, 5].Value ? ? string.Empty;
     if (value == null || value == String.Empty || value == "") {

      ws.DeleteRow(row, 1);

     }
    }
   }

   p.SaveAs(new FileInfo("c:\\Projects\\excel\\output.xlsx"));
  }
```

I try delete all rows where values in column with index 5 is empty

Comment: I have updated with minimal, complete example

Comment: @mason Everything Office-related starts at 1

Comment: Have you set up a breakpoint at `ws.DeleteRow(row, 1);`? Is it ever hit?

Comment: Yes, in breakpoint it works and shows me correct index row

Comment: Also I don't know how detect end of rows to summarize

Comment: Who can help with this issue, I have provided a full code

Comment: Why do you even need `for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)`?  Seems like your Column criteria is fixed at 5?  But to test, set a breakpoint on the Delete line and put a watch with `ws.Dimension` in it.  Step over the line and see if the Dimension goes down by one.  If it does, the problem is elsewhere, if not something else is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're looping from the top down. As you delete cells, excel will automatically shift the rest of the rows up, which will cause rows to be skipped when looping from the top down.

Try this for your loop:

```
 for (int row = end.Row; row >= start.Row; row--)
        {
            var value = ws.Cells[row, 5].Value ?? string.Empty;

            if (value.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                ws.DeleteRow(row, 1);
            }

        }
```

Couple of side notes:

- No need to loop through the columns if you are evaluating the same column every time. Just check the value of that cell for each row.
- `value` will never be null because of the `??` operator. You can simplify the if statement to just check for `String.Empty`.
- `String.Empty` and `""` are the same value so you only need to evaluate one or the other.
- When evaluating strings I would recommend using `.Equals()`. Using `==` can cause some bad results. 
  [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)