# Item not adding to arrayList correctly

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, element

So what I'm working on right now should be pretty simple. I'm adding an item to an `Arraylist`, and if the item's name is equal to the name of another item in the `Arraylist`, it gets rid of one of the items and just adds the numItem value to the other item. So for example, if a player buys "guns", and the numItem variable is set to 1500, it's added to an arraylist. If they input "guns" again, and that numItem is 2500, I want to get rid of one of the elements in the arrayList and just set the numItem of the remaining to 4000.

```
public void addItem(Item item)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this.ownedItems.size(); i++)
    {
        if(item.getName() == this.ownedItems.get(i).getName())
        {
            item.setNumItem(item.getNumItem() + this.ownedItems.get(i).getNumItem());
            this.ownedItems.remove(this.ownedItems.get(i));
        }
    }
    this.ownedItems.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you did not tag the language you are programming in, but i assume you use java. Your code should do the trick, if you change your string compare.

If you compare Strings by stating `string1 == string2` things will not go the way you would expect. Instead use `string1.equals(string2)`

You should read up on String compare: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

If you use C# i think the same principal more or less holds:

[C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

So change

```
if(item.getName() == this.ownedItems.get(i).getName())
```

into

```
if(item.getName().equals(this.ownedItems.get(i).getName()))
```