# Hello,how can i add && to a textbox and a string for user name and password,and how to close the first form Edited

Tags: c#

I want to perform a username and password check before allowing access to Form2. Form2 should only load if the `name` and `password` match. However, my code doesn't work and Form2 always loads. And also How can i close the first form when the second opens

```
 private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newForm = new Form2();
        if (txtbName.Text = "Georgi"&& txtbPassword.Text = "123" )
        {
            newForm.Show();
        }
}
```

Comment: You check for equality with double equals in C#. '=='

Answer (score 0):

You should use == (instead of =) to check. Obviously your code should not be used in a production application, storing passwords in code is not recommended.

```
   private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newForm = new Form2();
        if (txtbName.Text == "Georgi" && txtbPassword.Text == "123" )
        {
            newForm.Show();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use bellow code.
You should Use `==` to check for equality

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var newForm = new Form2();
   if (string.Equals(txtbName.Text.ToLower() , "Georgi".ToLower()) && string.Equals(txtbPassword.Text , "123"))
    {
      newForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newForm = new Form2();
    if (string.Equals(txtbName.Text, "Georgi") && string.Equals(txtbPassword.Text, "123"))
    {
        newForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Use the above code. For comparing strings in c# it is better to use **string.Equals** instead of **==**.
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals).

Answer (score 0):

You can do string comparison, there are lot of samples available in Google:

```
    private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newForm = new Form2();
        if (string.Equals(txtbName.Text ,"Georgi") &&string.Equals(txtbPassword.Text, "123" )
        {
            newForm.Show();
        }
   }
```

And this is for your reference [C# | Equals(String, String) Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-equalsstring-string-method/)