# Determine if object has field of passed type with specific child value

Tags: c#, reflection, field

I would like to know if it is possible to determine if an object has Fields with specific types (which I believe can be done with reflection using GetField(name)), and also to then determine if that field has a specific value.

For example, suppose we have the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Value;
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Value;
}

public class Abc
{
    public Foo Foo;
    public Bar Bar;
}
```

I would like to be able to be able to do the following:

```
public static class FieldChecker
{
    public static bool HasDesiredValue(Abc abcObject, Type fieldType, string value)
    {
        FieldInfo info = abcObject.GetType().GetField(fieldType.Name); //See notes below on why this is ok

        if (info != null && info.FieldType == fieldType)
        {
            //Here is my issue. This obviously isn't real code. Can something like this be done?
            if (abcObject.[FieldWithPassedInTypeAndName].Value == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
Abc abcObject = new Abc()
{
    Foo = new Foo()
    {
        Value = "SomeValue"
    }
};

bool boolOne = FieldChecker.HasDesiredValue(abcObject, typeof(Foo), "SomeValue"); //true
bool boolTwo = FieldChecker.HasDesiredValue(abcObject, typeof(Foo), "SomeOtherValue"); //false
```

**Notes:**

- The field name and the field type will **always** be the same, which is why I can use GetField(fieldType.Name). If there is a better way to do this I welcome feedback.
- The thing I'm interested in checking will **always** be called `Value`, and will always be a field on the field of the passed in type, so if there is a way to get the field, then `[whatever].Value` is what I'm interested in checking, nomatter what field type I pass in.
- There will only ever be 1 field with the desired type (i.e. there will never be 2 `Foo` fields in the `Abc` class, and even if there were I'm only interested in the field named `Foo`)
- In the real world, the Abc object is being generated using deserialization. I'm not initializing it in code.
- The Abc class was/is generated by a tool, so it cannot (shouldn't) be edited, so I can't make this a method in the Abc class. Also I'm interested in checking a lot of different values (in the real world the Abc class has tens of fields that I'm interested in checking) so a generic method would be the easiest I'm assuming.

Comment: Since you like reflection the main portion of the question (how to get property via reflection) is already answered by what I believe is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp), hopefully you know how to compare values (also [== vs. Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) may be a good read anyway) so you should be able to sort it out. I'd personally use `dynamic` and just compare the value `((dynamic)abcObejct.Value) == "SomeValue"`...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code:

```
// Check if the object has said property
public static bool HasProperty(this object obj, string property)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(property) != null;
}

// Get property value
public static object GetPropertyValue(this object obj, string property)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(obj, null);
}

public static bool HasDesiredValue(Abc abcObject, Type fieldType, string value)
{
    if (abcObject.HasProperty(fieldType.Name))
    {
        if (abcObject.GetPropertyValue(fieldType.Name).GetPropertyValue("value").ToString().Equals(value))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course you need plenty of validation and work around the edges to make this safe but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Side note: you've totally botched the only interesting part of the answer on how to compare the value... (getting value of the property is already [well covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) )