# How to use TMPro text in an if statement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game where you can type stuff into a text box and then things will happen onscreen, such as a box will move. Im using a script which will see what you wrote and depending on what you wrote it does something, e.g., if you type "hello" it will say hello in the debug log. I tried to do something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class TextToAction : MonoBehaviour
{
     public TextMeshPro Text;
     void Update()
     {
            if(Text.text = "hello")
            {
                    Debug.Log("hello");
            }
      }
}
```

but it wouldnt work. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have `if (Text.text = "hello")` this is a common rookie mistake,  you are testing there IF you can set Text,text to the word hello  not if it contains hello.. You meant `if (Text.text == "hello")`

Comment: @BugFinder actually you should not even use `Text.text == "hello"`, the correct way would be to use `Text.text.Equals("hello")` (see [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814878/7111561))

Comment: Did either of these suggestions help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class TextToAction : MonoBehaviour
{
     public TextMeshProUGUI text;
     void Update()
     {
            if(text.text.Equals("hello"))
            {
                    Debug.Log("hello");
            }
      }
}
```

You were using an *assignment operator*

- single `=` in `a = b`

instead you were expecting to perform a *comparison*

- Use `==` instead: `a == b`

However, when comparing strings you should use `string.Equals(string)` instead:

- `a.Equals(b)`