# Strange string comparison result

Tags: c#

I noticed that I get an unexpected result when I execute this:

```
object v1 = "Hallo";
object v2 = "Hallo";

char[] v3 = { 'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
object v4 = new string(v3);

bool resultOfTwoObjectsThatAreActuallyStrings = v1 == v2;
bool anotherResultOfTwoObjectsThatAreAlsoStrings = v1 == v4;

Console.WriteLine("First result: " + resultOfTwoObjectsThatAreActuallyStrings);
Console.WriteLine("Second result: " + anotherResultOfTwoObjectsThatAreAlsoStrings);
```

I would expect that I am doing exactly the same thing for both variables, but I get one time false and one time true.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) answer your question? You are not calling the `==` operator that takes 2 strings, which compares the characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: The missing piece I think is string interning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-5.0#remarks. `v1` and `v2` actually refer to the same object, because those string literals are interned as described in the above link. But the way you built `v4` string prevents that, so it refers to another object (even though that another object contains the same string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# operators aren't virtual.

When the compile-time type of the two variables is `object`, the operator `object == object` is used, which does a reference comparison. When the compile-time of the two variables is `string`, the operator `string == string` is used, which does a value comparison.

Why is `v1 == v2` true? Because compile-time constants are automatically interned - v1 and v2 both point to the same memory, and as such, the reference comparison returns true.

Why is `v1 == v4` false? Because you have two different objects with the same value, and the reference comparison returns false.

For bonus points, if you do `object v4 = new string(v3).Intern();`, you should get `v1 == v4` as true. But the correct approach is to use the `string == string` operator (or `string.Equals` and friends) when you want value comparison.

Do not rely on two strings with the same value to always have the same reference, nor all strings having a different reference. If you always do a value comparison, two equal references will still give you a quick "yep, they're the same"; if you have the two as `object` variables, you will *always* get reference comparison.