# Code that checks if there's a certain element in array, doesn't work as intended.(C#)

Tags: c#, console-application

So I run this piece of code:

```
  public class whatever
    {
        public  bool checkArray(object[] a, object x)
        {
            int goThrowArray = 0;
            bool res = false;
            while (goThrowArray != a.Length)
            {
                object tempVar  = a[goThrowArray];
                if (tempVar == x) 
                {
                    res = true;
                }
                goThrowArray++;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

And even when x equals a[goThrowArray]
It still returns false...
Example:

```
whatever checking = new whatever();
object[] s = { 1,2,3,54,62};
Console.Write(checking.checkArray(s,3));
```

[And then we run rest of the code in the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0fHz.png)

I tried changing data types, debugging  etc.
But no matter what it still returns false.

Comment: A couple question arise when I look at the code. 1) why do you use a while loop instead of a for or foreach loop. 2) why are you not implementing LINQ to search through the array. 3) are the datatypes meant to be object? In your code there would be no reason to have it as object (I assume you want to implement it in a wider scope I'd once again recommend using LINQ for this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `object` type encapsulates the ints (which are value types) in objects (which are reference types). This process is called [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). Objects are tested via reference equality. So, the object in the array is not the same object you are testing for. Even if both contain the same `int` value.

The resolution is to make the comparison with the [`Equals` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814878/880990), which is overriden for ints:

```cs
if (tempVar.Equals(x)) {
    res = true;
}
```

You can use a `object` array if you want to mix different types of objects, say `int`, `double` and `string` objects. But if you are only working with ints, then use a `int[]` instead. Then you will not have this problem.

You can even make your [method generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods), so that it will work with different types of arrays:

```cs
public bool CheckArray<T>(T[] a, T x)
{
    ...
}
```

The most common way to loop through arrays is to use a [for-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement).

Also, you can return immediately when a matching entry was found. Putting this together:

```cs
public bool CheckArray<T>(T[] a, T x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        if (a[i].Equals(x)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Test:

```cs
whatever checking = new whatever();
object[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 54, 62 };
int[] a2 = { 1, 2, 3, 54, 62 };
string[] a3 = { "hello", "world" };

Console.WriteLine(checking.CheckArray(a1, 3));
Console.WriteLine(checking.CheckArray(a2, 3));
Console.WriteLine(checking.CheckArray(a3, "world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `tempVar` and `x` are of type `object` the == operator resolves to `object.ReferenceEquals()` which always returns false for instances of boxed values. Either change that to `tempVar.Equals(x)` or change `object` to `int` in the signature of your function. You shouldn't use object when you know the correct type (int in this case), not only due to pitfalls such as this one, but also for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The first point When you find the desired object, `break the while loop`. And use `object.Equals` to compare two object

```
public class whatever
{
    public  bool checkArray(object[] a, object x)
    {
        int goThrowArray = 0;
        bool res = false;
        while (goThrowArray != a.Length)
        {
            object tempVar  = a[goThrowArray];
            if (tempVar.Equals(x)) 
            {
                res = true;
                break;
            }
            goThrowArray++;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's a good idea, it's irrelevant here. Since res is only assigned once, it keeps it's true value once it's set.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `object`, you should make that method generic, e.g.

```cs
public bool DoesArrayContainItem<T>(T[] a, T x)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == x)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

For one thing, that will force you to pass an item of the same type as the array. With the code you have, you could theoretically pass in an array of `int` and a `DataTable`. There would be no point doing that check and this method won't let you. It will also treat each type as itself, rather than all types as `object`. That means value types being treated as value types instead of being boxed.