How can types be both equal and not equal in C#? (.NET 8.0, Linux, custom .NET Host)

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 Linux
Framework: .NET 8.0.10
IDE: Rider (latest)

I'm creating a custom .NET Host from a native Linux project to run the managed code.
Problem is that I get a logical contradiction on comparing types in about 50% of the cases. The issue is 100% reproducible and happens only on Linux and with the custom .NET Host used.
It also affects the execution of the GetCustomAttributes method, which cannot find the attributes in such cases. Debugging led me to the situation visible on the screenshot, where types do not match, but when I compare them in the debugger (see the watch variable) they do match.

The exact same code works well (can match all types) if I run the managed code directly as a console executable, without the custom .NET Host.
I followed Microsoft's instructions to write a custom .NET Host:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting
Aside of the above issue the .NET Host works well, can load all assemblies and all other code appears to run well.

It is not a debugger issue, since the issue affects GetCustomAttributes (a standard library method) as well.
I've checked all projects and dependencies, they are good. Nullable is turned OFF on all projects and C# 11 is selected. I have only Library projects.
The IL code generated looks what one would expect.
UPDATE: It turned out to be false: No assembly is loaded twice.

What do I miss here? Misconfigured .NET Host? Having the Typo object loaded twice somehow? CLR or JIT bug?
Updates:

I've checked the assembly location on both type objects, they are the exact same.

This is a hint that the types indeed differ:


type.GetHashCode() = {int} 18014707
stopAtType.GetHashCode() = {int} 59387592


Related: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39783
Confirmed that the affected assembly is double loaded (Rider's Debug Output pane):

Loaded Assembly '/home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/Sandbox.Game.dll'
Loading module /home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/Sandbox.Game.dll in application domain 1:clr_libhost
Symbols for module /home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/Sandbox.Game.dll loaded
...
Loaded Assembly '/home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/Sandbox.Game.dll'
Loading module /home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/Sandbox.Game.dll in application domain 1:clr_libhost
Symbols for module /home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/Sandbox.Game.dll loaded

Printed the AssemblyLoadContext instances at the top of Main:
foreach (var assemblyLoadContext in AssemblyLoadContext.All)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"AssemblyLoadContext: {assemblyLoadContext.Name}");
}
Console.WriteLine($"AssemblyLoadContext.Default: {AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Name}");

Running directly (without the custom .NET Host):
AssemblyLoadContext: Default
AssemblyLoadContext.Default: Default

Running via the custom .NET Host:
AssemblyLoadContext: IsolatedComponentLoadContext(/home/viktor/se-dotnet-server-local/SpaceEngineersDedicated/bin/Debug/net8.0/SpaceEngineersDedicated.dll)
AssemblyLoadContext: Default
AssemblyLoadContext.Default: Default

It should explain the problem.
Code
Gist with the relevant .NET Host C++ code: https://gist.github.com/viktor-ferenczi/feff098dfe27bba0f03929a89e2994a4
Gist with the runtime config used: https://gist.github.com/viktor-ferenczi/9ba57aa40510ccd928e80570ddd54983
The RunManagedCode function is called with appropriate values. The managed code starts, so the strings passed are good.
(The rest of the project is a big mess now and very complex to compile, so it is not public, but will eventually be, should I succeed.)

Hi.  Please see how to ask and how to create an MRE.  In particular, paste code that reproduces the problem.  In isolation, pictures of code are not very helpful.

... though as a wild guess without being able to fully repro your issue, I'd try type.Equals(stopAtType) on line 49.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

System.Type overloads the equality and inequality operators.  Maybe that's what you are seeing?  If you could share a [mcve] as code rather than a screen shot I could be sure.

I've tried type.Equals(stopAtType) in the code and it gives the same result (false) as type == stopAtType. I've tried to add type.Equals(stopAtType) in the debugger as a watch and it produces the same contradictory true there.

I cannot share a minimal example easily, because I use a custom .NET Host to run the managed code as a library. The issue happens only if the managed code is running like that. If you just run the code separately as a console executable, then the issue does not happen.

@dbc Indeed, the Type overloads == and != operators. It boils down to the (object) this.UnderlyingSystemType == (object) o.UnderlyingSystemType comparison at the deepest level.

Then maybe there's a bug in your custom .NET Host.  For instance, maybe it loaded the same DLL twice.  Can you debug it?

IMHO push your code to a github repo, post an issue to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime politely asking someone to debug & code review

The .NET host initialization does not load any dependency DLL explicitly. I literally followed the Microsoft doc page. It loads a single C# library (assembly) and finds its dependencies automatically. I've also added a hook to assembly loading to see whether any of them are double loaded, but they are not.

The hash code of the two types differ, which confirms that they are different types, indeed. I just don't understand how it can be, because all other properties appear to match exactly.

Maybe related: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39783

Confirmed that the affected assembly is double loaded into the same application domain somehow.

OK so where do you get this assembly value from? Please show more code. How is it loaded, is it being loaded into a new load context somewhere? Possibly relevant https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56391

Narrowed down the problem to have two entries in AssemblyLoadContext.All. The first one is an IsolatedComponentLoadContext due to the use of the .NET Host I create from a native C++ process. The second item is the usual Default one. The type comparison issue is likely caused by that the assemblies those types are coming from are loaded into both contexts. Question is how can I get rid of the isolated context and use only the Default one, while still using a custom .NET Host?

@Charlieface Added the relevant parts of the code as GitHub Gists to the problem description above (look near at its bottom). The whole project is a big mess right now and not public yet, but eventually will be, should I succeed with this.

Finally found the right documentation: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/native-hosting.md

Strictly speaking, System.Type.FullName is not the type identity, it was never designed for this purpose. I don't understand why you even consider this property. If you use the == operator for two types and get false, they are different types, period.

From that issue it looks like it might be solved by using another bootstrap DLL. In other words the entry point from the native host shouldn't be one of the DLLs you are going to use, just a shim to start the rest of the app. What happens if you try that?

I tried to use a shim and it did not help. The next I try is to use a different "initialize" method to create the .NET Host. See the documentation I pasted 3 messages above.

The solution was to use the hostfxr_initialize_for_dotnet_command_line initialization method to create the .NET Host in the native Linux process.
The right code is in the documentation:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/native-hosting.md#running-app-with-additional-runtime-properties
Verified that we have only a single AssemblyLoadContext and that's the Default one. Also verified that all type comparisons work as expected.

Showing the actual code involved would improve this answer.

I've done exactly what is in the documentation section linked from my answer above. The rest of the code was unrelated to the problem.

It appears this is a known limitation of using a native host in .NET Core, in that any DLL called directly from native code will be loaded into an isolated AssemblyContext.
See this GitHub issue for a similar problem. It's not clear there what the workaround should be, but it seems one option would be to create a separate DLL to bootstrap the rest of the application from. So that DLL would be loaded into the isolated context, but everything else would be loaded into the default context.
You have also found some docs  (more of a design proposal than a guide) that imply it's possible to load directly into the default context. It's not made clear in that doc how to do so though.

Bootstrapping with another DLL did not help. I've tried that and it just produced issues elsewhere.
