# Help me to understand Equals() in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [== or .Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144530/or-equals)

why use `Equals()`  and not use `==`

```
    for (i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
   if (names[i].Equals(targetName))
   {
      index = i;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator most often checks for memory equality.

If the two objects you are checking are objects (or pointers), then this compares the *address* that the object is at.

The `.Equals()` functions is implemented by classes to check for equality between two objects. This function (where implemented in a class) will check data values in the objects instead of the memory address they live in.

Some objects override the `==` operator ([see the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144530/or-equals)), so both methods of checking for equality may work the same for some, but not all objects. Because of this, it's safer to use `.Equals()`.

Comment: According to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx
Your statement is not true.

Comment: `==` can be overloaded to use other comparisons than referential comparison. String is once popular example of this.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my answer to reflect this.